# Jquery pageredirect in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

Hi this is my jquery code to change the div content with another visualforce page but it is not working properly in the below code visualforce page is calling but src is taking as a blank.html

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/apex/mycustompage",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('.dash-graph-cont').html(data);
        //$('.dash-sulphur-cont').css('background-color','#f9afaa');
        $.getScript("js/chart-canvas.js");
        $('.graph-bar-icon').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.graph-line-icon').removeClass('active');
            $('.line-graph').css('display', 'none');
            $('.bar-graph').fadeIn();
        });
        $('.graph-line-icon').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.graph-bar-icon').removeClass('active');
            $('.bar-graph').css('display', 'none');
            $('.line-graph').fadeIn();
        });
        $(document).click(function () {
            $('.month-select-graph').fadeOut(100);
        });
        $('.month-select-graph,.dash-graph-head').click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
        $("#slider").slider();
        $('.dash-graph-head').click(function () {
            $('.month-select-graph').fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "src is taking as a blank.html". Suggest you use some of these techniques to debug yourself http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript.