# Javascript Button to prompt an alert

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am trying to write a javascript button that only redirects the user if the field Data_Confirmed__c = TRUE, it it is FALSE then they should receive an alert to confirm their data first. I am not getting any errors but it even though the field is FALSE it is still redirecting the user when it shouldn't.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

if({!Onsite_Review__c.Data_Confirmed__c}=="FALSE") {
alert("Please confirm the data.");
}
else{
window.open('/apex/loop__looplus?sessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}&eid={!Onsite_Review__c.Id}&contactId={!Onsite_Review__c.FSC_ContactId__c}&header=false&sidebar=false&hidecontact=true&tabclass=Custom51Tab&autorun=true&attach=false&ddpIds=a0Fa000000M3fOH');
}
```

Alternatively if I try to do the opposite and check if the field is != to "TRUE" then it always alerts and never opens the window when it should.

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

if({!Onsite_Review__c.Data_Confirmed__c}!="TRUE") {
alert("Please confirm the data.");
}
else{
window.open('/apex/loop__looplus?sessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}&eid={!Onsite_Review__c.Id}&contactId={!Onsite_Review__c.FSC_ContactId__c}&header=false&sidebar=false&hidecontact=true&tabclass=Custom51Tab&autorun=true&attach=false&ddpIds=a0Fa000000M3fOH');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your browser's inspect element feature (see e.g. [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript)) to see what text the Visualforce has generated. That will probably be:

```
if(false=="FALSE") {
```

or

```
if(true=="FALSE") {
```

neither of which are true (as JavaScript expressions).

So instead you need something like (as JavaScript is case sensitive too):

```
if("{!Onsite_Review__c.Data_Confirmed__c}"=="false") {
```

or better:

```
if(!{!Onsite_Review__c.Data_Confirmed__c}) {
```

Note that this code is appropriate if the page does not allow the field to be changed; if it did allow the field to be changed you would need to look at the current value of the input field.