# selectList onchange not working

Tags: rerender, pageblocktable, actionfunction, selectlist, commandlink

I have a VF page in which Im displaying set of records in  pageblocktable.

There is a dropdown List (Sort By) with values.  Name, Program and a commandButton named 'Reverse Order'.  So, when I select Name in the dropdown list, the pageblock table should sort By Name, similarly with Program duration. And when I click reverse order button, the order should change.

The reverse order button is working fine. The onchange of SelectList is not working. Below is my code.

VF Page

```
Sort By                                          
<apex:selectList value="{!sortExpression}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="doSearch();return false;" title="Sort By">
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!SortBy}"/>                                                
</apex:selectList>

<apex:commandLink action="{!reverseOrder}" value=" Reverse Order" reRender="pb" status="waitMsg" />    

<apex:actionFunction name="doSearch" action="{!searchStudentsList}" status="waitMsg" reRender="pb"/>
```

Apex class

```
public string sortExpression{get;set;}
public string sortDirection{get;set;}

public void ReverseOrder(){     
      sortDirection = (sortDirection =='DESC')? 'ASC' : 'DESC';//changes order by direction
      searchStudentsList();//calls search method
}

public void searchStudentsList(){
   //I use dynamic soql query using sortExpression and sortDirection in the query.
}

public ClassName{
In the constructor
    // Initializing stuff...
    SortBy = new list<SelectOption>();
    SortBy.add(new SelectOption('Name', 'Name'));
    SortBy.add( new SelectOption('Program__c', 'Program'));

    sortExpression = 'Name';
    sortDirection = 'ASC';
}
```

Comment: I suggest you narrow down the problem area by using the techniques in [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript).

Comment: "pb" is definitely the Id of an outer element?

Comment: well just to confirm do you have any required feel in the page (doesn't look like you have else reverse order shouldn't be working). and does the actionstatus fire ?

Comment: @RayDehler yes, pb is the outer element.

Comment: @Avidev9 I do not have any required fields. hmm I need to verify if the "onchange" of the selectList is working or not. how?

Comment: onchange event is working, i checked debug logs, it is calling the search method. May be this could be rendering issue.

Comment: No issue with rendering too!! :( it is being rendered correctly, but the list sorting isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crazy. The picklist value sorting will be based on how it is setup at the Field level irrespective of what we code.  Just read in Salesforce notes.

So, all I had to do was sort the picklist value in Alhabetical order at Field level. All ok now !!

Comment: please mark as an answer so others will know the issue is resolved

Comment: Yes, I couldn't mark it as solved immediately.  I had to wait for a day to do it as per the rules. And I forgot the next day.  Thanks for the reminder though. Cheers!