# Show Save Button When all Fields Fillled

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have a form with 2 fields.  When all fields' values are filled, I need to display/show the Register button in hide stage.  I am using jquery but it is not working.  Where did I make a mistake?

```
   <apex:page standardController="pop__c">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
  (function() {
 // alert('hi);
  $('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {

        $('input[id*=register]').attr('disabled', 'true');
    } else {
        $('input[id*=register]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
})()
  </script>

 <apex:form >

 FirstName:<apex:inputField value="{!pop__c.Name}" id="nid"/><br/>
 LastName:<apex:inputField value="{!pop__c.LastName__c}" id="fid"/>
 <apex:commandButton value="REGISTER" action="{!SAVE}"  disabled="true" id="register"/>
 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug code like this by adding `console.log` as described in [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript).

A key thing with jQuery is to add the event handlers (such as `keyup`) **after** the Document Object Model (DOM) is constructed and the common pattern for that is to use the [ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function. Your JavaScript was failing to add the `keyup` handler because at the time it ran the input elements were not in the DOM.

Your element matching of "form > input" only looks for input elements immediately inside form elements and Visualforce adds other elements in between. Using CSS classes is clearer and safer.

As well as changing the `disabled` attribute, to make the button's appearance change you have to add and remove the `btnDisabled` class.

This works:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('input.prerequisite').keyup(function() {
        console.log('keyup');
        var empty = false;
        j$('input.prerequisite').each(function() {
            if (j$(this).val() == '') empty = true;
        });
        if (empty) {
            j$('input[id*=register]').attr('disabled', 'true').addClass('btnDisabled')
        } else {
            j$('input[id*=register]').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('btnDisabled')
        }
    });
});
})()
</script>              
    <apex:form>
       FirstName:<br/>
       <apex:inputField styleClass="prerequisite" value="{!Account.Name}" id="nid"/><br/>
       LastName:<br/>
       <apex:inputField styleClass="prerequisite" value="{!Account.Site}" id="fid"/><br/>
       <apex:commandButton value="REGISTER" action="{!SAVE}" disabled="true" id="register"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```