# Visualforce - Apex - Google maps

Tags: apex, visualforce, google-map

I have been trying to get something to work with Google maps in combination with Apex and Visualforce pages, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
What I want is to set **different icons** with **different colors** in a Google map. More exactly, I want to modify an existing code that was doing the job but only with two icons, one for current location (Account object), and another icon for accounts around the current location.

If I take a look to the Visualforce page that is part of the Account page layout, which contains the Google maps, I can see this section of the code that takes care of the icons and some other stuff:

```
`var locations = 
[
  {!locationArray}
];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      for(var i=0;i<locations.length;i++) 
      {
          var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],locations[i][2]);
          bounds.extend(ll);
      }

      map.fitBounds(bounds);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i,mainX,mainY;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
{
  if(locations[i][3]!=-1)
    {     
      marker = new google.maps.Marker
      ({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,    
        icon: '{!$Resource.other}'
      });
   }       
   else
   {        
       marker = new google.maps.Marker
      ({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map,
         icon: '{!$Resource.current}'
      });             
   }       
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

// Remove focus
function setFocusOnLoad() {}`
```

So I though, ok, I want to add a different icon to each account base on a value of a custom field (**Point of Sales**), in the Account object.
What I did was to created a custom text field in the Account object, **Google_marker_URL__c**, to assigned a URL to different icons that are in the Documents object, base on the values in the **Point of Sales** field.
This was easy and it works! 
All I needed was to change the `icon: '{!$Resource.other}'`
to  `icon:'{!Account.Google_marker_URL__c}'`. 
The problem is that is picking up the **current account** Google_marker_URL__c for all the accounts around, which it is obvious... now :( 
So my question is, how can I change that? How can I use the icon that it is assigned to the accounts that are around the current account?

I have been trying all day different things but it won't work the way I want. 
I use four different icons with four different colors. Any ideas on how to change this code to do what I want?

Thanks.

---

22.07.2014 09:00PM

I'm adding the controller here:

```
 `public class DoorGoogleMap_CTRL
  {       
   public List<SelectOption> RangeOptions{
       get{
        List<SelectOption> listRangeOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(integer i=5; i<=50; i+=5){
       listRangeOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        return listRangeOptions;
    }
    set;
}   

public List<SelectOption> Units
{
  get
  {
    if(Units==null)//Units for filter purpose they show this units in picklist
    {
      Units=new List<SelectOption>();
      Units.add(new SelectOption('1.60934','mi'));
      Units.add(new SelectOption('1','km'));
    }
    return Units;
  }
  set;
}
public String selectedUnit{get;set;}
private boolean isDoor = false;
public boolean isMother=false;
public id currentAccountId{get;set;}//get the the current account id
private Account currentAccount;
private boolean isDeleted=false;
public DoorGoogleMap_CTRL(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{     
   Account acct=(Account)controller.getRecord();
   Account tmp_account;
    try 
    {
      tmp_account=[Select Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry, Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s,Deleted__c, Mother_ID_Checkbox__c,Door_Checkbox__c, Google_marker_URL__c from Account where id=:acct.id ];//get all information about mother because the system will prevent from use any column without querying them.
       currentAccount=tmp_account;
       isDoor=tmp_account.Door_Checkbox__c ;
       isMother=tmp_account.Mother_ID_Checkbox__c;
       isDeleted=tmp_account.Deleted__c;
       xCentral=currentAccount.Location__Latitude__s;
       yCentral=currentAccount.Location__Longitude__s;
       currentAccountId=acct.id;
     }catch(Exception e)
     {          
     }        
   }

    private List<Account> lstAccount=new List<Account>();
    private List<Account> filteredAccount;
    private void prepareLocationArray()
   {
    String sAddressInfo='';
    Decimal tmp_longitude,tmp_latitude;
    String tmp_googleIconMarker; 
    integer indicator=0;
    //if(locationArray==null)
    locationArray='';
    for(integer i=0;i<filteredAccount.size();i++)
    {     
     sAddressInfo='';     
     tmp_longitude=filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Longitude__s;
     tmp_latitude=filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Latitude__s;
     tmp_googleIconMarker=filteredAccount.get(i).Google_marker_URL__c; 
     if(tmp_longitude==yCentral&&tmp_latitude==xCentral)                
    {
     indicator=-1;
    }
    else
    indicator=i;

    // CVER: display the address information
       if(filteredAccount.get(i).BillingStreet != null)  
      sAddressInfo += '<br>' + filteredAccount.get(i).BillingStreet;  
       if(filteredAccount.get(i).BillingCity != null)  
      sAddressInfo += '<br>' + filteredAccount.get(i).BillingCity;  
       if(filteredAccount.get(i).BillingPostalCode != null)  
      sAddressInfo += ',' + filteredAccount.get(i).BillingPostalCode;  
       if(filteredAccount.get(i).BillingCountry != null)  
      sAddressInfo += '<br>' + filteredAccount.get(i).BillingCountry;
      if(sAddressInfo != '') sAddressInfo = String.escapeSingleQuotes(sAddressInfo);  

         String tmp_name;
         tmp_name=String.escapeSingleQuotes(filteredAccount.get(i).name.escapeXml());

         if(i<filteredAccount.size()-1)                            
            locationArray+='[\'<a target="_parent" href="/'+filteredAccount.get(i).id+'">'+tmp_name+'</a>' + sAddressInfo + '\','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Latitude__s+','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Longitude__s+','+indicator+'],';
         else
            locationArray+='[\'<a target="_parent" href="/'+filteredAccount.get(i).id+'">'+tmp_name+'</a>' + sAddressInfo + '\','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Latitude__s+','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Longitude__s+','+indicator+']';
    }
  }
    public String locationArray
   {
   get    
  {                                          
    if(locationArray==null)
    {     
      if(isMother)
         filterRange=100;
      else if(isDoor)
         filterRange=50;                                              
      locationArray= '';
      if(lstAccount.size()==0)
      {
         if(isDoor)
         {

           String SOQLQuery='';
           if(!isDeleted)
           {                 
             SOQLQuery='SELECT Id, Name, Point_of_Sale__c, Google_marker_URL__c, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry,Nielsen_ID__c, Location__Latitude__s,Location__Longitude__s FROM Account where Location__Latitude__s!=null and Location__Longitude__s!=null and Deleted__c=false and Door_Checkbox__c=true and DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+xCentral+','+yCentral+'), \'km\') <'+(filterRange+1);
             lstAccount=Database.query(SOQLQuery);                         
           }
           else
           {
             SOQLQuery='SELECT Id, Name, Point_of_Sale__c, Google_marker_URL__c, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry, Location__Latitude__s,Location__Longitude__s FROM Account where Location__Latitude__s!=null and Location__Longitude__s!=null and Deleted__c=true and Door_Checkbox__c=true and DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+xCentral+','+yCentral+'), \'km\') <'+(filterRange+1);
             lstAccount=Database.query(SOQLQuery);                             
           }
         }         
        filteredAccount=lstAccount;
      }

      SelectedUnit='1';
      //calculateDistance();          
      prepareLocationArray();
    }                              
    return locationArray;  
    }
    set;
    }  
    public Decimal xCentral{get;set;}  
    public Decimal yCentral{get;set;}
    public Decimal range
    {
    get{return filterRange;}
    set
    {
    filterRange=value;
    }
  }
  private Decimal filterRange;// use this variable to avoid auto fucos problem  
  public void calculateDistance()
 {      
   system.debug('filterRange'+filterRange);
    if(isMother)
    {           
        if(filterRange>100)
          filterRange=100;                                  
    }
    else if(isDoor)
    {       
        if(filterRange>50)
          filterRange=50;
    }               
    if(range<1)
       filterRange=1;            
    Set<Account> tmp_lstAccount=new Set<Account>();
    Decimal R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    Decimal dLat,dLon,a,c,d;
    Decimal rangeInKM;
    String theMarker;

    if(selectedUnit==null)
    {
       rangeInKM=filterRange*decimal.valueOf('1.60934');
    }
    else
        rangeInKM=filterRange*decimal.valueOf(selectedUnit);   

    for(Account tmp_account:lstAccount)
    {        
      try
      {  
        dLat = toRadians((xCentral-tmp_account.Location__Latitude__s));
        dLon = toRadians((yCentral-tmp_account.Location__Longitude__s));
        a = Math.sin(dLat/2)*Math.sin(dLat/2)+Math.cos(toRadians(tmp_account.Location__Latitude__s))*Math.cos(toRadians(xCentral))*Math.sin(dLon/2)*Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        d = R * c; // Distance in km
        if(d<=rangeInKM)
        {
           tmp_lstAccount.add(tmp_account); 
        }
      }catch(Exception ex)
      {
         ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
      }

    }     

    //if(tmp_lstAccount.size()>0)
    //{
        tmp_lstAccount.add(currentAccount);
        filteredAccount=new List<Account>();            
        filteredAccount.addAll(tmp_lstAccount);
       // system.debug('filtered'+filteredAccount);
       // locationArray=null;
        prepareLocationArray();
    //}        
   }
   private Decimal toDegree(Decimal val)
   {
    return (val*(180/3.14));
   }
   private Decimal toRadians(Decimal val)
  {      
  return (val*(3.14/180));   
  }    `
```

Comment: I want to add something. I have been trying all crazy stuff but still not working. The Visualforce page have a SOQL query  which eventually will become the **var Locations** that we can see on the Visualforce page. I was wondering if I can use that query to access the **Point_of_Sale__c**, and form there  use if statements in java script to determinate when to use an icon base on the point to sales's values.Is this possible? Gonna to try now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to put the marker URL is the `locations` array because that lets you define one per location.

So instead of:

```
  if(locations[i][3]!=-1)
    {     
      marker = new google.maps.Marker
      ({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,    
        icon: '{!$Resource.other}'
      });
   }       
   else
   {        
       marker = new google.maps.Marker
      ({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map,
         icon: '{!$Resource.current}'
      });             
   }
```

you could just have:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,    
        icon: locations[i][4]
        });
```

So the Apex code that builds the `locationArray` string should add an additional nested array entry for the marker URL (or replace the index 3 one that appears to just be a number with the marker URL).

Comment: Thanks for you answer Keith. I tried that but all I can see now are the default Google markers. I need to have the "current icon" to point out to the user the "current account".So maybe I should have said that I have 4 icons + the current location one. But, how do I connect the elements in the array location to their **Google_marker_URL__c**? 
The icon: location[i][4] only gave me the start ones...

Comment: @Viasur Yes you would have to make sure that the "current account" marker was also set properly in the array; probably easiest to make that a Document too so the same pattern is used. I'm afraid I don;t understand your last comment; I assumed that the controller could assign the right marker so that the generated locations array was correct. But are you saying something is done at the client-side to change to a marker other than the "start one(s)"?

Comment: Hello again Keith. Could you explain with a bit more details on how should I approach to this now? Or maybe point me out where in the controller I need to set the link to the new icons?

Comment: Probably here?:
`if(i<filteredAccount.size()-1) 
locationArray+='[\'<a target="_parent"   href="/'+filteredAccount.get(i).id+'">'+tmp_name+'</a>' + sAddressInfo +  '\','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Latitude__s+','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Longitude__s+','+indicator+'],';
  else
locationArray+='[\'<a target="_parent" href="/'+filteredAccount.get(i).id+'">'+tmp_name+'</a>' + sAddressInfo + '\','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Latitude__s+','+filteredAccount.get(i).Location__Longitude__s+','+indicator+']';`

Comment: @Viasur Yes there, though that code is pretty ugly already. Basically make the value of indicator the URL to the marker and reference that using `locations[i][3]` in the JavaScript.

Comment: what you are mentioning in your last post is not working. If I touch the indicator the map don't show up. What I have done is to substituted the indicator for the filteredAccount.get(i).Google_marker_URL__c but is not working. I'm missing something here?

Comment: The controller code you've posted doesn't appear to contain that change; for every change you make check your browser's JavaScript console to make sure there are no JavaScript syntax errors (see e.g. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript).

Comment: Hello Keith.Thanks for the tip, I already use that console. The **Indicator** is part of an if statement a few lines above that code. It indicates which account is the current one and which not. I can't override the indicator because the code needed to do that. Maybe I understood you wrong, when you are saying **make the value of indicator the URL**, you are saying to override the indicator with the line **filteredAccount.get(i).Google_marker_URL__c**?

Comment: @Viasur Yes that is what I was suggesting. Looking again just now, you'll also need to put quotes around it to make it a JavaScript string `',\''+indicator+'\']'`.

Comment: That works like a charm.The last issue is that now the current location is not using the unique current location icon even after changing the second target indicator to a custom URL field that contains the icon for the current account only. What it is that I missing here? 
Thanks so far for you help, it is much appreciate.

Comment: @Viasur In the controller, the logic that used to set locations[i][3] to -1 should instead set the URL to the current location URL. The JavaScript then no longer needs the two cases (as shown in my original answer).

Comment: sorry man, but I can't figure out this one. I get the icons for the accounts but can't fully understand how to link the current account with the current icon :(. I have removed the `else locationArray` target because is not doing anything. I have also changed the location java script in the visualforce page to your code on the your initial answer with the `location[i][3]` instead of [4]. This is the combination that at least sets the correct icons for the accounts, except the current icon. The current account uses the icon assigned by **Google_marker_URL__c**. Some other directions?

Comment: @Viasur You need to have the current account icon URL available in your controller and set that as location[i][3] instead of Google_marker_URL__c when the Account is the current Account.

Comment: next time I see you remind me to get you a bier or a pizza, what ever turn you on:) .. now is working. I had to make a few changes in some parts of the logic. I used the `tmp_longitude==yCentral&&tmp_latitude==xCentral` which was pointing the current account and then assign the icons to all the other accounts. This is more or less what you were saying. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Viasur - would be great if you could dump up the finalised code in the main body of the question. Any chance of that?