# How to query for opportunity in detail page button of Quote Page in javascript(on click javascript)?

Tags: opportunity, quote

I want to query for opportunity from Quote page
i.e. Detail page button of Quote on click of javascipt of that button..

```
alert({!Opportunity.StageName}); 
if('{!Opportunity.StageName}' =='F0') { 
alert('Can not Create Multiple Quote as Opportunity is moved to F0.'); 
}
```

This is what I am trying to do..on Detail page button of Quote but this alert is showing null value

Comment: What did you try ? Can you share your code ?

Comment: alert({!Opportunity.StageName});
if('{!Opportunity.StageName}' =='F0') 
{ 
alert('Can not Create Multiple Quote as Opportunity is moved to F0.'); 
}

This is what I am trying to do..on Detail page button of Quote but this alert is showing null value...

Comment: If you add javaScript you should always check your browser's JavaScript console. See e.g. [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript). Your alert is missing some quotes.

Comment: The thing is that opportunity is not getting queried and hence it is showing null value.
I have done same thing from list button on opportunity page and I am getting proper value, please suggest how can I perform this from Quote Detail page button?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```
 // Query the Quote  records based on QuoteId 
 var quoteResult =sforce.connection.query("Select
 Id,Discount,OpportunityId,Opportunity.StageName From Quote where
 Id='{!Quote.Id}'");

 // Getting the Opportunity StageName from Query 
 var quoteRecords = quoteResult.getArray("records"); 
 for (var i=0; i< quoteRecords.length; i++) 
 { 
   var quoteRecord = quoteRecords[i]; 
   opportunityStageName= quoteRecord.Opportunity.StageName; 
}
```