# oncomplete not working

Tags: actionsupport

I have a page where I use an actionSupport whenever a checkbox is changed and then I call an action in my controller. 
When this action is completed I want to call another function but it never gets called. Am I missing something?
here is my code:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="selectThisOne" action="{!selectAddressWithIdentifier}" />
                <table class="contact">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Naam</td>
                        <td>Adres</td>
                        <td>e-mail</td>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:repeat var="cont" value="{!contacts}">
                        <tr>    
                            <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cont.isSelected}">
                                <apex:actionSupport action="{!deselectAll}" oncomplete="selectThisOne()" status="{!$Component.one_moment}" event="onchange" immediate="true"/>
                            </apex:inputCheckbox></td>
                            <td>{!cont.address.Voornaam__c} {!cont.address.Achternaam__c}</td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    {!cont.address.Straat_1__c} {!cont.address.Huisnummer__c} {!cont.address.Huisnummer_Toevoeging__c}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {!cont.address.Postcode__c} {!cont.address.Plaats__c}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {!cont.address.Land__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>{!cont.address.E_mail__c}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>                    
                </table>
```

The two referenced functions are both public voids with nothing in them other than a System.Debug(); call

Comment: Try removing the immediate="true" from your actionSupport tag.

Comment: @VigneshwaranG still nothing :(

Comment: Are you saying the Apex `deselectAll` is called and runs to completion but the JavaScript `selectThisOne` isn't called?

Comment: @KeithC yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. I get the Debug Log from the deselectAll function but the Debug.Log from SelectThisOne is never there.

Comment: As `selectThisOne` has to be JavaScript do you  mean `console.log` doesn't output anything?

Comment: @KeithC well, selectThisOne is an actionFunction. So when I call the name it should call the apex function selectAddressWithIdentifier, which is a void in my controller that I can System.Debug()

Comment: OK. Then its time to start debugging; your browser's Developer Tools "Network" tab will show you the requests back and forwards and you should also be able to set a breakpoint in selectThisOne. See e.g. [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript).

Comment: @KeithC I think I know the flaw, I forgot to add the reRender tag, which just means that the entire page is reloaded -.- I don't understand why that is the default but there you go. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Well done for figuring it out.