# Javascript show/hide fields based on picklist value

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<apex:page controller="newOpportunityController" tabStyle="Contact" >
<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function hidefieldsforfemale()
        {
            if (document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.female}') == "Female" )
                {
                    document.write("inside female section");
                    document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id1}').style.display='none';
                    document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id2}').style.display='none';
                    document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id3}').style.display='none';
                 }
                else
                  {
                    document.write("inside male section");
                    document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id1}').style.visbility="visible";
                    document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id2}').style.visbility="visible";
                    document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id3}').style.visbility="visible";
                   }
            return true;
          }

</script>
```

```
  <apex:form  id="f1">
    <apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" rendered="{!showp2op1}" title="Members already added">
        <apex:outputPanel id="op1"  >
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactstoadd}" var="c" >
                  <apex:column value="{!c.firstname} {!c.lastname}" headerValue="Name" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!page3Next}" value="Confirmation" immediate="true" />
        </apex:outputPanel>


      </apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlock id="pb2" title="Member Information" mode="edit">

               <apex:pageblockSection id ="pbs1" title="Name and Contact" columns="2">
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.firstname}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.lastname}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.mobilephone}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.email}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.birthdate}"   />
               </apex:pageblockSection>

              <apex:pageblockSection id="pbs2" title="Member Details" columns="3">
                  <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Gender__c}" onchange="hidefieldsforfemale();" id="female" 
                                   onfocus="alert('focus on field')"  />
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Birthstar__c}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Related_to_Householder__c}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Know_Sanskrit__c}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Service_Interest__c}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Work__c}"/> 
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Upanayanam__c}" id="id1"/>                       
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Veda_Adhyayanam_Status__c}" id="id2"/>                       
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.Veda_Patasala__c}" id="id3" />                    
               </apex:pageblocksection>


                <apex:pageblockSection title="Address Information" columns="2">
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.mailingstreet}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.mailingcity}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.mailingstate}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.mailingcountry}"/>
                   <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.mailingpostalcode}"/>
               </apex:pageblockSection>




        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
             <apex:commandButton action="{!page1Next}" value="Previous" immediate="true" rendered="{!p2button1}"/>
             <apex:commandButton action="{!addmorecontacts}" value="Add more members" rendered="{!p2button2}"/>
             <apex:commandButton action="{!back2search}" value="Save & Back to search results" rendered="{!p2button3}"/>
             <!-- apex:commandButton action="{!page3Next}" value="Confirmation"  /-->

                <!--apex:commandButton action="{!saveacct}" value="Save"/ -->

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

When I chooose the picklist value of female, the fields with id1, id2 and id3 should be hidden. This is somehow not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, could this be done using VF itself. Please advise your thoughts.

Comment: Your browser's developer tools have "Inspect Element" where you can check the ID values, a Console where you can see console.log debugging output or coding errors and a full blown debugger. See e.g. [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript). Invest a bit of time in learning the basics with these tools. One problem I can see is that while there is a `getElementById` there is not a `getelementbyid`.

Comment: Thanks Keith. The getElementById suggestion worked..but, the fields are not still getting hidden. I went through the link but honestly feel a little overwhelmed and not sure where "exactly" to look. I was looking at the "console".

Comment: 'SAMEORIGIN'.
2Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://cs22.salesforce.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/jslibrary/1429643498000/sfdc/main.js:963 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. I also looked at the INSPECT element but didn't any evt listeners for "ONCHANGE"

Comment: Because Salesforce pages have a lot of JavaScript already you have to get used to ignoring messages not relevant to your problem. Adding console.log calls and watching out for them is the simplest way to start debugging. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<script>
function hidefieldsforfemale() {
    var gender = document.getElementById('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.female}').value;
    var display = gender == 'Female' ? 'None' : 'Inline';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id1}').style.display=display;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id2}').style.display=display;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id3}').style.display=display;
}
</script>
```

Your code was comparing the DOM element with "Female" rather than the `value` of that DOM element. You were also setting the `display` attribute in one case and the `visibility` in the other rather than flipping the value of one attribute.

On the question of whether it can be done in Visualforce, yes it can. You can re-render part of the page with `rendered` attribute of the `apex:inputField` set to a Boolean expression based on the gender value. The UI is a bit slow to respond (compared to the instant response you get with JavaScript) but the code is cleaner and that approach is more in keeping with the design of Visualforce.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I was actually troubleshooting and realized both the mistakes. Thanks for pointing out. I tried the code you gave but still the fields are NOT hiding...

Comment: @JJSHHS The above worked for me in a stripped down version of your page. So you'll have to debug further. Note that without more work in the JavaScript its just the fields and not the field labels that are hidden. You should give the non-JavaScript approach a go.

Comment: On taking a closer look, I realized that of the 3 fields that I want to hide, one of them is getting hidden (it's a text area field) but the labels are not hidden, the other 2 fields are picklists and they're not getting hidden. How do I hide the labels and fields =)

Comment: OK, what is the non-Javascript approach that I should take? Action Function?

Comment: Update - When I tried to do this, var d1=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f1.pb2.pbs2.id1}').style.display;
              alert(d1), the field is removed from the page, but at the end of the function, it shows the field back again...what's causing the display to be set to true again?

Comment: Keith, with regards to using the re-render part of the attribute and doing it in VF, I don't see a re-render attribute for the apex:inputfield component. If so, what criteria do I have to set to trigger the re-render attribute. I wasn't sure and hence took the JS route.

Comment: @JJSHHS You should be able to find examples by Googling. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Keith- Thanks so much for your help. I found the problem. The picklist that was not getting hidden because it was a dependent picklist based on a controlling picklist. When I did remove the dependency, I was able to hide the field. But, I don't get why it wouldn't let the dependent picklist hide by itself using JS =)

Comment: @JJSHHS Good you've figured it out. With Salesforce the JavaScript logic (and styling) you add is always working in combination with the JavaScript logic (and styling) Salesforce adds. So when something doesn't work as you expect you need to debug (or give up and take a different approach).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to go down the path of using actionsupport and calling the method in the controller. I'm still not able to get this to work...the system.debug itself isnt' getting called which makes me believe that the action method isn't getting triggered. Any thoughts?

Update below from Jul 6,

OK, I did a scaled down version of actionsupport and it's working. However, when I add a required field like Contact's last name to the page, SF somehow "wipes" out the other fields from the page. Any ways to get around it?

```
<apex:page controller="testActionSupport">
<apex:pageblock>
    <apex:form>
            <apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.lastname}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="id3" value="{!cont.gender__c}" >
                    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!checkgender}" immediate="true"/>
                </apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputfield id="id4" value="{!cont.Upanayanam__c}" rendered="{!id4rend}" />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:form>
```

```
  public class testActionSupport {
    public Contact cont{get;set;}
    public Boolean id4rend{get;set;}

 public testActionSupport(){
    if (cont==null) {cont = new Contact();}
    id4rend=false;
 }
public void checkGender(){
    system.debug('inside checkGender');
    if (cont.gender__c == 'Male'){
        id4rend=true;
    }
    else
    {id4rend=false;}

}

}
```