# JQUERY - Unable to get it to work

Tags: visualforce, jquery

This basic JQUERY isn't working...Can someone see what is that I'm missing?

```
<apex:page controller="newOpportunityController">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
alert('inside JQUERY');

j$("document").ready(function() {
        j$("#id3").on('change',checkGender);
        j$("#id3").on('click', test);
        console.log('test message');
});

function checkGender(){
    var gender = j$("#id3");
    alert(gender.val());

    if((gender.val() == 'Female'){
       j$("#id4").hide();
    }
    else {
        j$("#id4").show();
    }
}

function test(){
  alert('JQUERY is working');  
 }

</script>


  <apex:pageblock>
    <apex:form>
            <apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:inputField id="id3" value="{!cont.gender__c}" />
                <apex:inputfield id="id4" value="{!cont.Upanayanam__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:form>
 </apex:pageblock>  

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where is your controller code? and what is the actual issue you are coming across?

Comment: Suri, the controller code is virtually nothing...I was trying to do a sample test to do some show/hide based on field values.

Answer (score 2):

Visualforce prefixes the ID that you specify with the ID values of the containing elements. (Use your browser's "View Source" or similar to see this.)

One way to handle this with jQuery is to use [jQuery's ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector. So instead of:

```
j$("#id3")
```

use:

```
j$("[id$='id3']")
```

**PS**

There is also a spurious `(` on the line that tests for `'Female'`. Pasting the script into http://jshint.com/ helps find that sort of error (as does looking at your browser's JavaScript console).

**PPS**

Here is some working code (just using a standard controller and a custom gender field I have in my org:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:pageblock>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:inputField id="gender" value="{!Contact.cve__gender__c}" />
            <apex:inputfield id="name" value="{!Contact.Name}" />
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageblock> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$("document").ready(function() {
   var gender = j$("[id$='gender']");
   var name = j$("[id$='name']");
   function checkGender() {
       if (gender.val() == 'Female') {
           name.hide();
       } else {
           name.show();
       }
   }
   gender.on('change', checkGender);
});
</script> 
</apex:page>
```

Further problems were:

- the script tag that includes jQuery needs to be separate from the script tag that contains your local code
- Salesforce defaults the ID values of fields to a patter that ends in values like "id3" and "id4" so the ID values need to be more distinct to avoid matching the wrong element
- more of a code style thing, but repeating the jQuery selectors makes maintenance harder so best to only have them once in the code
- more of a performance thing, but best to render the HTML first and then load the JavaScript so your page appears quicker (i.e. JavaScript at the end)

Comment: Hi Keith, I'm not sure why but it's not working...I tried both of your suggestions above.

Comment: @JJSHHS I'm afraid its time to [debug](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript) then...

Comment: @JJSHHS ... or see the working code I added to the answer.