# Form fields not binding inside apex repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have a generic component that works for all objects. The object name is passed as a parameter to the component. I am iterating through a list to display a component for each object. Here is the code:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!objectNameList} var="obj">
    <c:SobjectComp objectName="{!obj}" />
<apex:repeat>
```

The component has a form that displays fields of the object that are included in the object's fieldset. But when I submit the form, the values are not binding.

However, the same code works without apex:repeat. The following works:

```
<c:SobjectComp objectName="Custom_Object1__c"/>
<c:SobjectComp objectName="Custom_Object2__c"/>
<c:SobjectComp objectName="Custom_Object3__c"/>...
```

The form values bind to controller when using the above code. It is the same component but does not work with apex:repeat.

Please help.

Comment: Using your browser's "Inspect Element" feature to compare the HTML generated for the non-working and working case might give some insight.

Comment: There is no difference in the HTML being rendered. Is it something to do with the order of page markup rendering and execution of getter/setter in the component controller?

Comment: Your two code examples are different: one has (presumably) a separate object  per component while the other is using the same object per component. (Also usually apex:repeat inserts a number into the ID in the HTML; not sure what manually repeating does.) You can look at what goes over the network for both cases using the "Network" tab of your browser's [developer tools](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript) - might provide some extra info.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having a similar issue with repeaters and components.