# How to debug Javascript in Chrome on a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm developing some javascript in a visualforce page, however when I get an error in the dev tools console and I click the link to the script, it just comes up a blank script the majority of the time like so:

[image]

Sometimes It'll work as expected, but 99% of the time I get the above, does anybody know what's up?

Comment: try to click on console error before page completely loads

Comment: try this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna/related?hl=en

Comment: Open the Developer Tools before you go to that page (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools) as that usually ensures that all the JavaScript is loaded in the debug tools so the link will take you to the code. (Some general stuff here [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript).)

Comment: @KeithC Thanks Keith! If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Developer Tools before you go to that page (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools) as that usually ensures that all the JavaScript is loaded in the debug tools so the link will take you to the code.

(Some general stuff here [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript))