# Chrome dev tools stopped working

Tags: visualforce, javascript, chrome

I have faced the problem described in this question

[How to debug Javascript in Chrome on a Visualforce page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102623/how-to-debug-javascript-in-chrome-on-a-visualforce-page)

earlier opening dev tools before opening visual force (or clearing the cache) page resolved the problem in the past.

However since August 8th 2016: 1) I can NOT see the code as shown in the screenshot above. 2) The console.log commands in my javascript from my Visualforce page work 3) Any functions I call from the command line do not work. 4) There are no exceptions thrown when I type any commands even no "Uncaught ReferenceError:" This is happening only for visualforce page iframe and not the TOP frame.

My environment: Windows 8.1, Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I've already asked this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136355/salesforce-breaking-javascript-console

Comment: It's also been asked in less detail here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133220/102

Comment: Update to version 53 and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that:

The problem is caused because of the visualforce main.js over riding the window.Map function. Following the steps in this Article resolves the issue [Native JS Map prototype is overwritten in Visualforce page w/ a header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103924/native-js-map-prototype-is-overwritten-in-visualforce-page-w-a-header)

Comment: no link to `Article` in your answer; please add