# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: createLineItem is not defined

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I keep getting this *Uncaught ReferenceError: createLineItem is not defined* for this line of code. It comes up in the console whenever I click on the "Create Line Item" button. I'm super uneducated with coding (slowly trying to learn) and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Here is the code:

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Line_Items__c" fields="Id,Amount__c,Date_of_Transaction__c,Description__c,Individual_Account__c,P_Card_Expense__c,Stage__c,RecordTypeId"/>
</apex:remoteObjects>

<div class="mypage">
Amount:
<input type="text" id="amount"/>
Date of Transaction:
<input type="date" id="date"/>
P-Card Expense?:
<input type="checkbox" id="pcard"/>
Description:
<input type="text" id="description"/>
<button onclick="createLineItem()">Create Line Item</button>
</div>

<script>
function createLineItem(){
    var LineItemAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var LineItemDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var LineItemPCard = document.getElementById("pcard").value;
    var LineItemDescription = document.getElementById("description").value;
    var LineItemRecordType = "012o0000000pnHd";
    var LineItemAccount = {!Individual_Account__c.Id};
    var LineItemStage = "Pending Hard Copy";
    var LineItem = new SObjectModel.LineItem();
LineItem.create({Amount__c: LineItemAmount}, function(error, records) {
    if (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    } else {
        sforce.one.navigateToSObject(records[0]);
    }
});
};
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you just remove `<button onclick="createLineItem()">Create Line Item</button>` and instead `<input type="button" onclick="createLineItem()" value="Create Line Item"/>` try once ?

Answer (score 2):

One reason the function definition is not completing (and so the function is not available when the click happens) is because of missing quotes - add them here:

```
var LineItemAccount = "{!Individual_Account__c.Id}";
```

This:

```
var LineItemAccount = a085000000JJwBOAA1;
```

is not valid JavaScript but this (with quotes added) is valid:

```
var LineItemAccount = "a085000000JJwBOAA1";
```

Use your browser's "View Source" to see what is output by the Visualforce and check that it looks right. Also look in your browser's console for JavaScript errors. See e.g. [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `;` after the closing of the function `createLineItem()`

`};`(this one)

```
</script>
```