# Issue with JqxTabs after Winter 16

Tags: canvas

we are using **JqxTabs** for Tabbed Content. In one of the JqxTabs, we embedded **Apex Canvas app** which plays video content. The functionality works fine before **Winter 16 release**. After **Winter 16 release**, request for video content was not happening due to JqxTabs. I have verified this by removing the JqxTabs functionality.

Thanks,
Nani

Comment: Suggest you check your browser's developer tools e.g. console and network to see what is happening. See e.g. [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript). Quite possibly no-one who uses this forum has come across this specific problem.

Comment: From Winter 16 release, Canvas App was wrapped in two <iframe> tags (https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_canvas_double_iframe.htm). When i debug the page using browser tools, page has only one iframe tag with id as "canvas-outer-_:". Inner "canvas-inner-_ iframe was not generated.