# Javascript to calculate total at row and column level

Tags: visualforce, javascript, dynamic-visualforce

I have a pageblocktable with one editable column in which numeric value for quantity will be entered. the next column to this is the Rate column which will have values from Salesforce. I want the Product of these 2 to be displayed in the last column as Total and also the sum of the Total column in Javascript so that on entering values in the inputtext, the total dynamically changes.

Below is my page :

```
<apex:page controller="DetailController" sidebar="false" id="pg">
<script>
function findTotal(){
alert(document.getElementById('pg:frmId:pb:pbt:0:qty').value);
//    alert(document.getElementById('pg:frmId:pb:pbt:0:j_id38').txt);
var qty = document.getElementById('pg:frmId:pb:pbt:0:qty').value;
var rate = document.getElementById('pg:frmId:pb:pbt:0:j_id38').text; 
var totallineItem = qty*rate;
//    document.getElementById('pg:frmId:pb:pbt:0:qty').value
document.getElementById("pg:frmId:pb:pbt:0:j_id26").innerHTML = totallineItem ; 
}



</script>
<apex:form id="frmId">


<apex:pageBlock title="Order Line Items" rendered="{!showDetails}" id="pb">
<apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton action="{!createOrder}" value="Save"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!DispWrapper}" var="dw" id="pbt">
<apex:column value="{!dw.lineItemObj.Product__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!dw.lineItemObj.Order__c }"/>
<apex:column headerValue="Delivered Quantity" >
<apex:inputtext value="{!dw.quantity}" id="qty" onchange="findTotal();"   styleClass="count-me"/>
 </apex:column>
 <apex:column value="{!dw.lineItemObj.Rate__c }" id="rate"/>
 <apex:column headerValue="Total">
 <apex:outputtext id="litotal"></apex:outputtext>
 </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

I am not familiar with Javascript and so this code is all I have which I tried. Please point me in the right direction to proceed with this!

The sample image below shows a typical table. The last column and the summary (Totals) need to be populated via Javascript.
[image: Sample Table]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DOM Id values in Visualforce tables include a row number (the `:0:` in your JavaScript) so your logic needs to incorporate that. The approach that I think works best is to use a CSS class (that has no markup associated with it) instead of the DOM Id:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Delivered Quantity" >
    <apex:inputtext value="{!dw.quantity}" styleClass="quantityMarker"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column value="{!dw.lineItemObj.Rate__c }" styleClass="rateMarker"/>
<apex:column headerValue="Total">
    <apex:outputtext styleClass="totalMarker"/>
    <apex:facet name="footer">
        <apex:outputtext styleClass="grandTotalMarker"/>
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

While you could achieve what you want with just JavaScript, I would recommend adding (as a static resource) and using jQuery in your page. The code then becomes something like this (that you should add to the end of the page so the page rendering is not held up):

```
<script src="{!$Resource.jQuery}"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.quantityMarker').change(function() {

            var defaultedFloat = function(s) {
                if (s !== null && s !== '') {
                    var r = parseFloat(s);
                    if (!isNaN(r)) return r;
                }
                return 0;
            };

            // Recalculate the row
            var q = $(this);
            var r = q.closest('tr').find('.rateMarker');
            var t = q.closest('tr').find('.totalMarker');
            // Better handling of rounding may be needed
            t.text(defaultedFloat(q.val()) * defaultedFloat(r.text()));

            // Recalculate total of all rows
            var total = 0;
            $('.totalMarker').each(function() {
                var t = $(this);
                total += defaultedFloat(t.text());
            });
            $('.grandTotalMarker').text(total);
        });
    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
```

This code:

- Executes `jQuery.noConflict()` so any existing value of `$` in the page is preserved
- Waits until the DOM is ready
- Then adds a function that is notified of changes on all elements that have class `.quantityMarker`
- When a change happens, the function finds the class `rateMarker` element in the same row and the `totalMarker` element in the same row
- Then sets the product in the `totalMarker` element
  = Then sums all the row totals into the grand total

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Keith. I have included jQuery file in my static resource and then tried your code. is there something else that needs to be done to populate the Totals column as its still not getting populated - do i need to include javascript code like document.getElementById('total').value= value obtained from jQuery?

Comment: I've typed this code in without trying it myself so there are probably mistakes in it but I think its pretty much complete. The first thing to do is look at your browser's console for errors and you can add `console.log` calls to the above code as the most simple debugging technique. But if you are going to write JavaScript you need to learn about debugging techniques for it e.g. [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript) as most of us makes mistakes when writing it.

Comment: I just pasted the original code into http://jshint.com/ and fixed two problems in the code - I've updated the code in the answer. Doesn't guarantee the code will work, but at least makes sure its syntactically correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Keith. I was able to do a bit of debugging and the code is working fine now as I am getting the desired result in the Totals column. However, can you please also guide me to get the value of Total of the Totals column below the table (could be part of table itself or separately). I believe the grandtotalmarker is supposed to calculate that, but how do i display the same on my page? (really sorry for asking very basic questions!!!!)

Comment: I've added to the Visualforce making use of the `apex:facet name="footer"` to add a `grandTotalMarker` cell at the bottom of the total column.

Comment: Thats great! Just one small issue I am still facing - If the table has multiple entries, on entering the quantity for the first line item i am getting NaN as the result in total and then on entering the second one it works fine. Is there a way to make that as 0 or the correct value instead of NaN

Comment: See addition of `defaultedFloat` function to answer.

Comment: Thats  awesome Keith..Just one last thing - How do I store the value available in Totals in a Custom Object field. I already have a save function with me, but I am not sure how to pass the value which appears in the Totals column each time for each row. Tried using <apex:param> in Outputtext, but its coming out to be null. Do i need to set that as well in the jQuery script?

Comment: You can add an `apex:inputHidden` next to the `totalMarker` field and also update that (using the `val` function). Or you can just repeat the calculation at the server side as its trivial.

Comment: Thanks a ton Keith! I replicated the calculation server side to resolve this.

Comment: `noConflict` isn't necessary when using closures.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Not sure what you mean by that. If you examine the source, you will see that the `noConflict `function restores the value of `$` that jQuery has set to itself using `window.$ = _$`. So executing the function immediately after jQuery is pulled in is the safe approach (though rarely necessary).

Comment: You're passing it by argument. You're not referencing `window.$` within the closure. So it's not necessary.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes those lines of code are using the $ passed in. But you are missing the point that without noConflict lines of JavaScript following this code will have $ defined to be jQuery when those lines of code may expect $ to be something else. The point is to avoid jQuery making a global change.

Comment: Hmm fair enough. It won't break *your* code, but it might break someone else's.