# Uncaught Action failed: aura:if$controller$handleTheTruth [Cannot read property '$getReference$' of null]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, error-messages

We are facing an error in our lightning component. All seems to be working good but unnecessarily this error pops up.
Suppose I have performed any task from button click in the component, all will run on first time button if I do same thing once again then all the functionality get performed well but it shows error . Problem is not only with button click but also on other events such as onChange of text etc.

Below is the screenshot of the error :

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Can anyone help in this?

Thanks,

​Abhinav

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: I suggest you use the [browser debugger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript) to check for a null value that it looks like you are passing in to the Lightning framework from your code.

Comment: can you share your code please?