# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object : tmpVar1

Tags: null-pointer

For some reason the variable does not get assigned.

What I am trying to do is to pass a set of ids to VF page from a list button.

Here's my VF code:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Electricity_Meter__c" extensions="findSupplier" recordSetVar="meters">
    <apex:pageblock >
      <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ApplicableMeterReturn}" var="Rec">
          <apex:column headerValue="Company Name" value="{!Rec.Supplier__r.name}"/>
      </apex:pageblockTable> 
    </apex:pageblock>  
</apex:page>
```

Here's the extension:

```
public class findSupplier {
      Public      List<sobject>           metersToQuote      {get;set;}  
    public findSupplier(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
      mycon = controller;
      metersToQuote = mycon.getSelected();
    }
    ApexPages.StandardSetController mycon;
    List<electricity_meter__c> MeterList = [Select id,name,AQ__c,meter_details__c,Profile_Class__c 
                                            from electricity_meter__c where (id IN: metersToQuote)]; 


    public list<applicable_meter__c> getApplicableMeterReturn(){    
          list<Quote__c> oldQuotes = new list<Quote__c>();
          list<applicable_meter__c> applicableMeters = new list<applicable_meter__c>();

          string supplierQueryString = 'select Supplier__r.name from Applicable_Meter__c ';
          string supplierGroupModifier = ' group by Supplier__r.name';
          string supplierWhereCondition;

          for (sobject meters: MeterList){
                if (supplierWhereCondition == null) {
                    supplierWhereCondition = 'WHERE ';
                } else {
                    supplierWhereCondition += ' OR ';
                }
              string meterAQ = string.valueOf(meters.get('AQ_C'));
              supplierWhereCondition += '(min_aq__c => \'' + meterAQ + '\'      )           ';
          }
    applicableMeters = Database.query(supplierQueryString + supplierWhereCondition + supplierGroupModifier);   
    return applicableMeters;
    } 
}
```

EDIT:

I've pulled the error from the debug log:

```
15:44:08.088 (88086257)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[8]|Aggregations:0|select id, name, AQ__c, meter_details__c, Profile_Class__c from electricity_meter__c where id IN :tmpVar1
15:44:08.090 (90911470)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[8]|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

Comment: What line is the error happening? What debugging have you done?  Your title mentions `tmpVar1` but there is no `tmpVar1` variable in your code.

Comment: Good point. I've pulled this from the debug log.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code would be a good place to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing the query that references `metersToQuote` outside of any method, so I presume what is happening is that that code is being executed before the body of the constructor that initialises `metersToQuote`.

Test case that illustrates that the constructor runs later than the field initialisation:

```
@isTest
private class MyTest {
    private class MyClass {
        Integer i = 1;
        MyClass() {
            i = 2;
            j = 4;
        }
        Integer j = 3;
    }
    @isTest
    static void test() {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        System.assertEquals(2, c.i);
        System.assertEquals(4, c.j);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I've moved the query into `getApplicableMeterReturn` method and it solved the problem.