# Force.com IDE debugger Issue

Tags: force.com, force.com-ide

I am facing the following error from Eclipse force.com debugger when i tried to debug the apex code.

> Encountered an error executing remote command Your Salesforce org
>   doesn't have the permission to debug Apex.

Could any one please help me on this issue?

Comment: See this: [Debug Apex Code in Eclipse](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_debugging_debugger.htm)

Comment: That's not a standard feature, and I've heard it's quite expensive.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005JFtIAM See This

Comment: ...or this [Apex debugging in Winter '16 - how well does it work?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94881/apex-debugging-in-winter-16-how-well-does-it-work).