# How to debug trigger in eclipse

Tags: apex, trigger

I am studying the code who has written by other programmer. there are bunch of classes and triggers. i want to check the flow of the trigger. How to see hirarchy and how to set breakpoints to trigger?

Comment: You can use System.debug or System.assert

Comment: without using system.debug  is there is any way i can see the flow of trigger?

Comment: For this you need to run practical scenarios of your application. Run them and check the trigger code. I only know this point for trigger flow.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Link:

[The Apex Interactive Debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2TvQ3rtpV0&index=83&list=PLScnZWsj0lrQSep5OZ33UVXmlgHbX6BYt)

[Getting Started with the Apex Debugger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_overview.htm)

- The Apex Debugger extends the Force.com IDE plug-in for Eclipse and does most of the things you expect a debugger to do. Use it to:
  Set breakpoints in Apex classes and triggers.
- View variables, including sObject types, collections, and Apex System types.
  View the call stack, including triggers activated by Apex Data Manipulation Language (DML), method-to-method calls, and variables.
- Interact with global classes, exceptions, and triggers from your installed managed packages. (When you inspect objects that have managed types that aren’t visible to you, only global variables are displayed in the variable inspection pane.)
- Complete standard debugging actions, including step into, over, and
  out, and run to breakpoint.
- Output your results to the Console window.

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74003/force-com-ide-debugger-new-feature) post from @sfdcfox would be really helpful regarding debugging with Eclipse tool.