# Getting error:-"NewCaseSendEmail: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101"

Tags: apex, soql

```
trigger NewCaseSendEmail on Case (after insert, after update) {
      system.debug('inside Case after insert update trigger*****');

            if(Label.EXECUTE_TRIGGER == 'False')
                return ;

            //Subhash Garhwal - 12/26/2016 - Added Record Type check to exclude XVELA and Interschalt record types
            //Code Modified By Karthikeyan Ramamurthy - WeServetech 21-03-2017
            //Included the new xvela record types.
            Case[] cases = [select id, AccountId, CaseNumber, type, subject, Product__c, Priority, RecordType.Name from case where id in :Trigger.new  
                            And RecordType.DeveloperName Not IN('XVELA' ,'XVELA_Question','XVELA_Dongle','XVELA_Error','XVELA_Sales','Interschalt')]; 

            CustomEvent__c[] events  = [select id,date__c,useralias__c,User_Alias__c, start__c, end__c from customevent__c where 
            (start__c <= :System.Now()) and (end__c >= :System.Now())];
            system.debug('eventsr*****'+events);
            System.debug('YYYYY'+cases); 
            for(Case currentCase :cases){
                if(events.size() > 0 && currentCase.AccountId != null)
                {                    
                     system.debug('currentCase*****'+currentCase);  
                    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
                    { 
                        system.debug('Trigger.isUpdate'+Trigger.isUpdate);
                        Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(currentCase.ID);
                        if(currentCase.Priority.equals(oldCase.Priority))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    CustomEvent__c currentEvent = events[0];
                    list<Settings__C> settingsList = [select id,priorities__c from settings__c LIMIT 1];
                    Settings__C settings;
                    if(settingsList != null && !settingsList.isEmpty()){
                        settings = settingsList[0];
                    }else{
                     //add error if no settings record present   
                     //trigger.newMap.get(currentCase.Id).addError('No Settings have been created. Please create settings.'); 
                    }

                    list<Account> accList = [select id,priorities__c,site from account where id = :currentCase.AccountId];
                    Account account;
                    if(accList != null && ! accList.isEmpty()){
                        account = accList[0];   
                    }else{
                     //add error if no settings record present   
                     //trigger.newMap.get(currentCase.Id).addError('No Account associated with Case'); 
                    }

                    String debugForContent = ''; 
                    system.debug('account.Id --->' + account);
                    system.debug('currentEvent.useralias__c*******'+currentEvent.useralias__c);
                    system.debug('settingsc*******'+settings);
                    system.debug('accountc*******'+account);

                    if(settings != null && account != null && currentEvent.User_Alias__c != null)
                    {

                        List<String> accountPriorities = new List<String>();
                        List<String> settingsPriorities= settings.Priorities__c.split(';');
                        system.debug('settingsPrioritie+++++++++++++++'+settingsPriorities);
                        if(account.Priorities__c == null)
                        {
                            accountPriorities= new List<String>();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          accountPriorities =  account.Priorities__c.split(';');
                        }
                        system.debug('accountPriorities+++++++++++++++'+accountPriorities);
                        list<Contact> relatedContactList = [select id,phone from contact where accountid = :account.Id];
                         Contact accountFirstContact;
                        if(relatedContactList != null && !relatedContactList.isEmpty()){
                            accountFirstContact = relatedContactList[0];
                        }
                        String contactPhone = '';
                        system.debug('currentEvent.user_alias__c -->' + currentEvent.user_alias__c);
                        list<User> userList = [select Instant_Messager_ID__c from user where CommunityNickname = :currentEvent.user_alias__c and isActive = true];
                        User eventAttachedUser;
                        if(userList != null && !userList.isEmpty()){
                            eventAttachedUser = userList[0];
                        }
                        system.debug('eventAttachedUser-->' + eventAttachedUser);
                       // List<User> eventAttachedUsers = [select Instant_Messager_ID__c from user where CommunityNickname = :currentEvent.useralias__c];
                        //If (eventAttachedUsers  !=null && eventAttachedUsers.size()>0) {
                       // User eventAttachedUser =eventAttachedUsers[0];
                        // System.Debug(eventAttachedUser);
                        if(accountFirstContact != null)
                        {
                            contactPhone = accountFirstContact.Phone;
                        }

                        Boolean canContinue = false;

                        if(accountPriorities != null && settingsPriorities != null)
                        {                
                            for(String i : accountPriorities){
                                for(String j : settingsPriorities){
                                debugForContent = debugForContent + ' '+i+'-' +j;
                                    if(i.equals(j)){
                                        canContinue = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if(!canContinue) {        
                           if(currentCase.Priority == '1 Critical')
                           {
                               canContinue = true;
                           }
                           else
                           {                
                               canContinue = false;
                           }
                        }
                        system.debug('canContinue-->' + canContinue);            
                        if(eventAttachedUser  ==null || eventAttachedUser.Instant_Messager_ID__c == null)
                        {
                            canContinue = false;
                            system.debug('$$$$'+canContinue);
                        }        
                        System.debug('HELLO' + eventAttachedUser + ' with priority' + currentCase.Priority + canContinue);                        
                        if(canContinue)
                        {            
                            system.debug('%%%');
                           // Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);         
                            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {eventAttachedUser.Instant_Messager_ID__c}; 

                            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                            mail.setSenderDisplayName('SalesForce Case Trigger');
                            mail.setSubject('Critical Case Alert: #'+ currentCase.CaseNumber + ' ' + account.Site + ' ' 
                                + currentCase.Type+', Ph ' + contactPhone );
                            mail.setBccSender(false);
                            mail.setUseSignature(false);
                            mail.setPlainTextBody(
                            'Case: ' + currentCase.CaseNumber 
                            +'\n'
                            +'Subject: ' + currentCase.Subject
                            +'\n'
                            +'Account : ' + account.Site
                            +'\n'
                            +'Product : ' + currentCase.Product__c
                            +'\n'
                            +'Contact #: ' +contactPhone
                            );

                            mail.setHtmlBody(
                            'Case: ' + currentCase.CaseNumber 
                            +'<br/>'
                            +'Subject: ' + currentCase.Subject
                            +'<br/>'
                            +'Account : ' + account.Site
                            +'<br/>'
                            +'Product : ' + currentCase.Product__c
                            +'<br/>'
                            +'Contact #: ' +contactPhone
                            );

                            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

                       }
                  }
             } 

    }     

}
```

Comment: The SOQL's written in for loop are causing an issue. You need to bulkify your logic using List and Map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.LimitException: Too Many SOQL Queries: 101 in Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51962/system-limitexception-too-many-soql-queries-101-in-trigger)

Comment: Please use some Google. Your problem has a design nature and you should look at some Apex Trailheads or [Apex Best Practice: Bulkify Your Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code) before. The number of questions regarding 101 LimitException in Salesforce Stack Exchange and in Web in overall is uncountable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code is not written considering the best practices. There are multiple **select** queries written inside the for loop which should never be used.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices
follow this link and update the code accordingly.