# Trigger issue: If case.priority changes then contact .priority changes too

Tags: trigger

```
trigger prioritycheck on Case (before insert, after update) {
    Set<ID> setacc = new  Set<ID>();
    for(case c : trigger.new){
        setacc.add(c.accountid);
    }
    Map<Id,List<Contact>> bottlemap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
    List<Contact> tempList;

    for(case c : trigger.new){
        if(bottlemap != null && bottlemap.containskey(c.accountid)){
            tempList = bottlemap.get(c.accountid);
        }

        for( contact con: tempList){
            List<Contact> conList;
            conlist = new List<Contact>();
            conlist = bottlemap.get(c.accountid);
            if(c.priority == con.priority__c){
                c.contactid = con.id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the trigger? Are you getting a compile time error?

Comment: trigger is not working no error are coming but the values are same as previously

Comment: There is a error on line "c.priority=conlist.priority__c", You cannot get the priority value from the list. And also can u elabporate your question I am not able to understand it.

Comment: i am making a trigger on case...    case.priority should be equal to contact.priority?

Comment: As an Account can have many child Contact records, you first need to decide how to determine a single priority value for an Account. For example should it be the maximum priority value from all the child Contacts? Also the code and title don't seem to match.

Comment: if case.priority  changes so all Contact records should be changed,kindle help in code @KeithC

Comment: @tandonprateek can u help

Comment: Are you trying to update all Contact records when a Cases priority changes?

Comment: yeaa @BarCotter

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing but based on the comments you are trying to update all Contact records when a Cases priority changes.

The (untested) code below should achieve this or at least give you an idea of how to achieve it.

```
trigger prioritycheck on Case (after update) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        Map<Id, String> accountIdToPriority = new Map<Id, String>();
        for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
            // Only fire when priority changes
            if (c.priority__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).priority__c) { 
                accountIdToPriority.put(c.accountId, c.priority__c);
            }
        }
        List<Contact> contacts = [select AccountId 
                                  from Contact
                                  where AccountId in :accountIdToPriority.keySet()];

        for (Contact con : contacts) {
            con.priority__c = accountIdToPriority.get(con.AccountId);
        }
        if (contacts.size() > 0) {
            update contacts;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Apex trigger prioritycheck caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: prioritycheck: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.AccountId: Trigger.prioritycheck: line 15, column 1..  @barcotter

Comment: I have updated my answer to fix that issue

Comment: its not making any change as after updating the value the values are same .@barcotter

Comment: This trigger is untested so I am not sure why its not fully working. It could possibly be that `priority__c` is not being changed on `Case`. The code is to give you an idea of what you need to do to achieve your requirements. I suggest you have a look at [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code) and then see which bits of the code are being executed.

Comment: @parth you cant expect people to write code for you.  Try putting in a few debug statements in the if condition to see if priority is getting changed at first place. Also check if there are any workflows which is resetting the priority in contact. The code provided in the answer by barCotter should work, unless you have made any additional changes to it