# Can any one correct this one why batch apex is not deleting records?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

Here is my batch apex .it is not deleting records

```
global class BatchProcessorder implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    String query;
    DateTime lastTwoDays = DateTime.now().addDays(-30);

    global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Query = 'SELECT ID FROM order_batch__c where CreatedDate >:lastTwoDays'; 
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<order_batch__c> scope){
       List<order_batch__c> oppList = new List<order_batch__c>();
       for(order_batch__c a : scope){
       if(a.Save_order__c=false) 
           oppList.add(a);
       }
       delete oppList ;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

I have scheduled two to three time with changes .still the same it is happening

Comment: Are you getting any error?If so please post the debug log.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are not deleting any records is because your `if` statement is incorrect. It's assigning `false` to the `Save_Order__c` field, and then returning false to the `if` keyword

You should be using `==` in the below code:

```
   if(a.Save_order__c=false) 
       oppList.add(a);
```

The code below will work correctly:

```
   if (a.Save_order__c == false) 
       oppList.add(a);
```

Have a look at [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code) to get more information on debugging issues like this.

Comment: That's one reason I prefer `if(!a.Save_Order__c)` instead of `if(a.Save_Order__c==false)`-- it's less likely to cause problems if you have a typo. Also, it's worth explaining that the reason why `if(a.Save_Order__c=false)` doesn't work is because it's assigning `false` to the `Save_Order__c` field, and then returning false to the `if` keyword, and thus skips the body of the `if` block.

Comment: @sfdcfox always adding value. I've updated my answer to include why the `if` statement wasn't working. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the query you have used returns records. Also check if any of the records meets the criteria specified in the execute method.