# Unable to call controller extension method from test class

Tags: unit-test

I have a custom object which is a child to the Opportunity object. The custom object is viewed via visualforce page. Sometimes Users need to create payment records for the child object. This is achieved by calling a method on a controller extension. When pressed, the method will automatically create detail records using information in the custom object record.

I am trying to write a test class that will check the controller is working correctly and that the values copied over from the custom object are correct. I can't figure out how to call the method to create the payments. Can anyone help? 
Here is the test class:

```
@isTest                 
public class sipExt_Test {
    public static testMethod void testSIPExtController() {

    // Create Opportunity from test utilities class
    List<Opportunity> OppList = testUtilities.createTestOpps(1); 

    // Create the SIP
    bonus_calculator__c bc1 = new bonus_calculator__c(opportunity__c = OppList[0].Id);
    insert bc1;    

    PageReference ref = new PageReference('/apex/SIP2?id=' + bc1.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(ref);

    // Create SIP standard controller, pass it the SIP Record
    ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(bc1);

    // Pass the Controller to the Extension
    sipExt stdController = new sipExt(controller); 

    stdController.createPayments();           

    // Query for Payments fields
    List <Bonus_Payments__c> bPayList = [SELECT Id FROM Bonus_Payments__c WHERE Bonus_Record__c = :bc1.Id];    

        system.debug(bPayList[0].id);                

    }
}
```

Comment: If `createPayments` is the method you are talking about then you are calling it correctly. What is not working?

Comment: When I query for the bonus payments at the bottom, I get an out of bounds error message which suggests that no records are being created.

Comment: OK, then there is a bug in either sipExt or the test code. I suggest you do some debugging yourself - see [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code) - and if you can't figure out what is wrong also post the sipExt code.

Comment: I agree - I spent most of yesterday afternoon doing this. Thanks for taking a look all the same. I will post up the solution when I get there.

Comment: With some help, I found that the sales_associate values were null in the extension despite being populated when executed via the UI.

Comment: Keith, if you move your last comment to an answer i will select it. I had to do some debugging so you were right.

Comment: I've done that but your fix might help others you could post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `createPayments` is being correctly made.

So there is a bug or bugs in either `sipExt` or the test code. I suggest you do some debugging yourself - [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code) - and if you can't figure out what is wrong also post the `sipExt` code.

Comment: Some notes on how I debugged this:

To debug this, I ran the process via the UI as an end user would and then monitored the results in the Dev Console. 

I then executed the apex test which simulates this process and monitored the results in the Dev Console. By comparing the results I was able to see that some key fields were not being updated when run through the Apex test. I was then able to update the test class as required.