# unable to cover 100% of the code in testclass

Tags: unit-test

trigger

```
trigger cptmpaddtoperadd on Student__c (before insert,before update) 
{
     for(student__c s: Trigger.new)
        {
          if (s.Copy_temp_addr_to_perminant_address__c )
           {
           s.Perminant_address__c=s.Temp_address__c; //  getting not covered at this point

           } 
         }
}
```

test class :

```
@istest
public class testcopytmptoper 
{   
     static testmethod void copytmptoper()
    {
       Training__c t = new Training__c();
        t.Name = 'cptmptoper';
        insert t;
        Batch__c b = new Batch__c();
        b.Training__c = t.Id;
        insert b;
        student__c std = new student__c();
        std.Batch__c = b.Id;
        std.Name = 'krish';
       if(std.Copy_temp_addr_to_perminant_address__c == true)
        std.Temp_address__c = 'hyderabad';
         insert std;
          list<student__c> ss = [select id,Temp_address__c,Perminant_address__c from student__c where id =:std.Id];
           system.assertEquals(ss[0].Perminant_address__c,ss[0].Temp_address__c);
         }
}
```

can anyone help me with this ...!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What lines aren't covered and what are you struggling with in getting them covered?

Comment: Try adding debug statements to your code so you'll know what's going on.  See [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code/36616#36616).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Trigger, you are checking whether `Copy_temp_addr_to_perminant_address__c` is true, but in Test Class, this field is not set to true.
Please try updating this line `if(std.Copy_temp_addr_to_perminant_address__c == true)` in test class to `std.Copy_temp_addr_to_perminant_address__c = true;`

Comment: Thanks Siva by removing if condition the code was able to cover the 100% ...!!