# I have written a test class for Batch apex and could not find code coverage?

Tags: unit-test, batch

```
global class gz implements database.batchable<sobject>{
global database.querylocator start(database.batchablecontext bc)
{
string sn='closed won';
string query='select id,name,stagename from opportunity where stagename=:sn';
return database.getquerylocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<opportunity> opplist){
for(opportunity opp:opplist)
{
opp.description='Your Stage is in Progress';
string val1=opp.name;
string val2='-';
string val3='Update';
string result='';
result=string.valueof(val1)+string.valueof(val2)+string.valueof(val3);
opp.name=string.valueof(result);
}
update opplist;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}

Test Class:
@istest
public class gz_Test{
static testmethod void gz_Test()
{
opportunity opp=new opportunity(name='xxxx',stagename='xxxxx');
opportunity opp1=new opportunity(name='xxxx',stagename=opp.stagename);
update opp1;
}
}
```

Comment: simply updating an opportunity in the test class won't cause the batch to execute. See the Apex doc on testing batch classes

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, in order to create an opportunity, you first must create an account and associate the opportunity with the account. Check your organization's required fields for a new account and a new opportunity. If you don't satisfy those requirements, your accounts and opportunities won't insert.

Add debug statements to your code and look at your debug logs. See [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code/36616#36616).

Comment: How to write this line in test class

Comment: string sn='closed won';
string query='select id,name,stagename from opportunity where stagename=:sn';

Comment: Hello crmprogdev sir how to above line in test class

Comment: Are you asking me how to write a dynamic query? If so, since it's a test class, do you expect it to change and if not, why do you  need it to be dynamic? See the [SOCL and SOSL Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index.htm) on how to write queries.

Comment: actually, and I didn't learn this until recently, you can insert Oppos without Accounts, `accountId` is not a required field - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm#topic-title. The standard UI forces an AccountId but apparently not DML.

Comment: Note that he's doing an Update to Opportunity records. Opportunity is on the detail side of a M-D relationship with Account. One can't update unparented records. In most real orgs, validation rules would prevent an Opp from being created without an associated Account.