# Trying to Build Email that sends Summary of Objects

Tags: email

I am trying to setup a schedulable email in an apex class. It queries a custom object (used as an analytic snapshot) then pull the information from the objects to build a formatted email. I am getting stuck in sending the email - when I remove all but a couple of the variables, it sends, otherwise is fails. I guess because it is too many lines? Are there ways to simplify the code?

Code:

```
public class PentathlonUpdate {

    public static void sendMail(string message) {


    Map<String, Decimal> Points = new Map<String, Decimal>();
    Map<String, Decimal> PointsGoal = new Map<String, Decimal>();
    Map<String, Decimal> PointsPercent = new Map<String, Decimal>();
    List<Pentathlon_Points__c> PentathlonPoints = [SELECT Team__c, YTD_Points__c, Point_Goal__c, Goal_Percent__c
                        FROM Pentathlon_Points__c
                        WHERE CreatedDate = Today];
        For(Pentathlon_Points__c PP: PentathlonPoints){
            Points.put(PP.Team__c, PP.YTD_Points__c);
            PointsGoal.put(PP.Team__c, PP.Point_Goal__c);
            PointsPercent.put(PP.Team__c, PP.Goal_Percent__c);
            }

        Decimal AATTP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 1') ? Points.get('Team 1') : 0;
        Decimal AGP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 2') ? Points.get('Team 2') : 0;
        Decimal FBP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 3') ? Points.get('Team 3') : 0;
        Decimal PHP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 4') ? Points.get('Team 4') : 0;
        Decimal STP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 5') ? Points.get('Team 5') : 0;
        Decimal WPBCPP = Points.ContainsKey('06 - WPB&CP') ? Points.get('06 - WPB&CP') : 0;
        Decimal COP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 7') ? Points.get('Team 7') : 0;
        Decimal MSP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 8') ? Points.get('Team 8') : 0;
        Decimal MSCBP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 9') ? Points.get('Team 9') : 0;
        Decimal PPLP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 10') ? Points.get('Team 10') : 0;
        Decimal OFFP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 11') ? Points.get('Team 11') : 0;
        Decimal ONEP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 12') ? Points.get('Team 12') : 0;
        Decimal ONMP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 13') ? Points.get('Team 13') : 0;
        Decimal ONWP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 14') ? Points.get('Team 14') : 0;
        Decimal CHEMP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 15') ? Points.get('Team 15') : 0;
        Decimal REFP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 16') ? Points.get('Team 16') : 0;
        Decimal AUSP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 17') ? Points.get('Team 17') : 0;
        Decimal UKP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 18') ? Points.get('Team 18') : 0;
        Decimal ECANP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 19') ? Points.get('Team 19') : 0;
        Decimal WCANP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 20') ? Points.get('Team 20') : 0;
        Decimal UTP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 21') ? Points.get('Team 21') : 0;
        Decimal PSP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 22') ? Points.get('Team 22') : 0;

        Decimal AATTPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 1') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 1') : 0;
        Decimal AGPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 2') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 2') : 0;
        Decimal FBPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 3') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 3') : 0;
        Decimal PHPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 4') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 4') : 0;
        Decimal STPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 5') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 5') : 0;
        Decimal WPBCPPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('06 - WPB&CP') ? PointsGoal.get('06 - WPB&CP') : 0;
        Decimal COPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 7') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 7') : 0;
        Decimal MSPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 8') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 8') : 0;
        Decimal MSCBPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 9') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 9') : 0;
        Decimal PPLPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 10') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 10') : 0;
        Decimal OFFPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 11') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 11') : 0;
        Decimal ONEPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 12') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 12') : 0;
        Decimal ONMPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 13') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 13') : 0;
        Decimal ONWPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 14') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 14') : 0;
        Decimal CHEMPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 15') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 15') : 0;
        Decimal REFPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 16') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 16') : 0;
        Decimal AUSPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 17') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 17') : 0;
        Decimal UKPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 18') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 18') : 0;
        Decimal ECANPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 19') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 19') : 0;
        Decimal WCANPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 20') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 20') : 0;
        Decimal UTPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 21') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 21') : 0;
        Decimal PSPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 22') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 22') : 0;

        Decimal AATTPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 1') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 1') : 0;
        Decimal AGPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 2') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 2') : 0;
        Decimal FBPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 3') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 3') : 0;
        Decimal PHPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 4') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 4') : 0;
        Decimal STPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 5') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 5') : 0;
        Decimal WPBCPPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('06 - WPB&CP') ? PointsPercent.get('06 - WPB&CP') : 0;
        Decimal COPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 7') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 7') : 0;
        Decimal MSPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 8') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 8') : 0;
        Decimal MSCBPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 9') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 9') : 0;
        Decimal PPLPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 10') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 10') : 0;
        Decimal OFFPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 11') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 11') : 0;
        Decimal ONEPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 12') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 12') : 0;
        Decimal ONMPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 13') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 13') : 0;
        Decimal ONWPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 14') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 14') : 0;
        Decimal CHEMPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 15') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 15') : 0;
        Decimal REFPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 16') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 16') : 0;
        Decimal AUSPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 17') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 17') : 0;
        Decimal UKPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 18') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 18') : 0;
        Decimal ECANPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 19') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 19') : 0;
        Decimal WCANPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 20') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 20') : 0;
        Decimal UTPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 21') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 21') : 0;
        Decimal PSPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 22') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 22') : 0;

        Decimal PointTotal = (AATTP + AGP + FBP + PHP + STP + WPBCPP + COP + MSP + MSCBP + PPLP + OFFP + ONEP + ONMP + ONWP + CHEMP + REFP + AUSP + UKP + ECANP + WCANP + UTP + PSP);
        Decimal PointGoalTotal = 410000;
        Decimal PointPercentTotal = (PointTotal / PointGoalTotal * 100);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'email@email.com'});
        mail.setSubject('Points (TESTING)');
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setHtmlBody(
            '<html><font size=2 face=Arial>' +     
            '<b><u>Points:</u></b><br/>' + 
            'Team 1:  ' + AATTP.format() + ' / ' + AATTPG.format() + ' / ' + AATTPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 2:  ' + AGP.format() + ' / ' + AGPG.format() + ' / ' + AGPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 3:  ' + FBP.format() + ' / ' + FBPG.format() + ' / ' + FBPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 4:  ' + PHP.format() + ' / ' + PHPG.format() + ' / ' + PHPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 5:  ' + STP.format() + ' / ' + STPG.format() + ' / ' + STPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 6:  ' + WPBCPP.format() + ' / ' + WPBCPPG.format() + ' / ' + WPBCPPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 7:  ' + COP.format() + ' / ' + COPG.format() + ' / ' + COPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 8: ' + MSCBP.format() + ' / ' + MSCBPG.format() + ' / ' + MSCBPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 9:  ' + MSP.format() + ' / ' + MSPG.format() + ' / ' + MSPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 10:  ' + PPLP.format() + ' / ' + PPLPG.format() + ' / ' + PPLPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 11:  ' + OFFP.format() + ' / ' + OFFPG.format() + ' / ' + OFFPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 12:  ' + ONEP.format() + ' / ' + ONEPG.format() + ' / ' + ONEPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 13:  ' + ONMP.format() + ' / ' + ONMPG.format() + ' / ' + ONMPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 14:  ' + ONWP.format() + ' / ' + ONWPG.format() + ' / ' + ONWPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 15:  ' + CHEMP.format() + ' / ' + CHEMPG.format() + ' / ' + CHEMPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 16:  ' + REFP.format() + ' / ' + REFPG.format() + ' / ' + REFPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 17:  ' + AUSP.format() + ' / ' + AUSPG.format() + ' / ' + AUSPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 18:  ' + UKP.format() + ' / ' + UKPG.format() + ' / ' + UKPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 19:  ' + ECANP.format() + ' / ' + ECANPG.format() + ' / ' + ECANPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 20:  ' + WCANP.format() + ' / ' + WCANPG.format() + ' / ' + WCANPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 21:  ' + UTP.format() + ' / ' + UTPG.format() + ' / ' + UTPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            'Team 22:  ' + PSP.format() + ' / ' + PSPG.format() + ' / ' + PSPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
            '<b>TOTAL:  ' + PointTotal.format() + ' / ' + PointGoalTotal.format() + ' / ' + PointPercentTotal.setScale(0) + '%</b><br/>' + 
        '</font></html>');
        // Send the email
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

    }   
    public static testMethod void testSendMail() {
        sendMail('This is my email message');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but test methods can no longer be included within classes. You'll want to remove the test method at the end of your class.

Comment: What sort of failure are you getting? I'm not aware of any governor limit on method length (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) but your error will be helpful in debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

> when I remove all but a couple of the variables, it sends, otherwise is fails. I guess because it is too many lines? Are there ways to simplify the code?

Yes, and that's likely what you'll need to do. Let's try breaking this up into a couple of separate methods and classes where the first one creates the body (and a corresponding list of recipients should you expand the code). The 2nd one assembles the message body along with the email address and subject, then sends it. Also, since you're querying the content, you don't need the (string message) argument in your constructor.

I think if you make revisions along those lines as in the example code I've created below, it should move you towards solving your problem. Additionally, you'll want to add some debug statements at appropriate places. I also recommend you read [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code/36616#36616).

```
public class PentathlonUpdate {

    public static void composeData() {

       Map<String, Decimal> Points = new Map<String, Decimal>();
       Map<String, Decimal> PointsGoal = new Map<String, Decimal>();
       Map<String, Decimal> PointsPercent = new Map<String, Decimal>();
       List<Pentathlon_Points__c> PentathlonPoints = [SELECT Team__c, YTD_Points__c, Point_Goal__c, Goal_Percent__c
                        FROM Pentathlon_Points__c
                        WHERE CreatedDate = Today];
       For(Pentathlon_Points__c PP: PentathlonPoints){
          Points.put(PP.Team__c, PP.YTD_Points__c);
          PointsGoal.put(PP.Team__c, PP.Point_Goal__c);
          PointsPercent.put(PP.Team__c, PP.Goal_Percent__c);
       }

       Decimal AATTP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 1') ? Points.get('Team 1') : 0;
       Decimal AGP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 2') ? Points.get('Team 2') : 0;
       Decimal FBP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 3') ? Points.get('Team 3') : 0;
       Decimal PHP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 4') ? Points.get('Team 4') : 0;
       Decimal STP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 5') ? Points.get('Team 5') : 0;
       Decimal WPBCPP = Points.ContainsKey('06 - WPB&CP') ? Points.get('06 - WPB&CP') : 0;
       Decimal COP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 7') ? Points.get('Team 7') : 0;
       Decimal MSP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 8') ? Points.get('Team 8') : 0;
       Decimal MSCBP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 9') ? Points.get('Team 9') : 0;
       Decimal PPLP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 10') ? Points.get('Team 10') : 0;
       Decimal OFFP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 11') ? Points.get('Team 11') : 0;
       Decimal ONEP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 12') ? Points.get('Team 12') : 0;
       Decimal ONMP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 13') ? Points.get('Team 13') : 0;
       Decimal ONWP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 14') ? Points.get('Team 14') : 0;
       Decimal CHEMP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 15') ? Points.get('Team 15') : 0;
       Decimal REFP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 16') ? Points.get('Team 16') : 0;
       Decimal AUSP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 17') ? Points.get('Team 17') : 0;
       Decimal UKP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 18') ? Points.get('Team 18') : 0;
       Decimal ECANP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 19') ? Points.get('Team 19') : 0;
       Decimal WCANP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 20') ? Points.get('Team 20') : 0;
       Decimal UTP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 21') ? Points.get('Team 21') : 0;
       Decimal PSP = Points.ContainsKey('Team 22') ? Points.get('Team 22') : 0;

       Decimal AATTPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 1') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 1') : 0;
       Decimal AGPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 2') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 2') : 0;
       Decimal FBPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 3') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 3') : 0;
       Decimal PHPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 4') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 4') : 0;
       Decimal STPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 5') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 5') : 0;
       Decimal WPBCPPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('06 - WPB&CP') ? PointsGoal.get('06 - WPB&CP') : 0;
       Decimal COPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 7') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 7') : 0;
       Decimal MSPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 8') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 8') : 0;
       Decimal MSCBPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 9') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 9') : 0;
       Decimal PPLPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 10') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 10') : 0;
       Decimal OFFPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 11') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 11') : 0;
       Decimal ONEPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 12') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 12') : 0;
       Decimal ONMPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 13') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 13') : 0;
       Decimal ONWPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 14') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 14') : 0;
       Decimal CHEMPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 15') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 15') : 0;
       Decimal REFPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 16') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 16') : 0;
       Decimal AUSPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 17') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 17') : 0;
       Decimal UKPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 18') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 18') : 0;
       Decimal ECANPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 19') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 19') : 0;
       Decimal WCANPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 20') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 20') : 0;
       Decimal UTPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 21') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 21') : 0;
       Decimal PSPG = PointsGoal.ContainsKey('Team 22') ? PointsGoal.get('Team 22') : 0;

       Decimal AATTPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 1') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 1') : 0;
       Decimal AGPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 2') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 2') : 0;
       Decimal FBPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 3') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 3') : 0;
       Decimal PHPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 4') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 4') : 0;
       Decimal STPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 5') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 5') : 0;
       Decimal WPBCPPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('06 - WPB&CP') ? PointsPercent.get('06 - WPB&CP') : 0;
       Decimal COPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 7') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 7') : 0;
       Decimal MSPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 8') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 8') : 0;
       Decimal MSCBPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 9') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 9') : 0;
       Decimal PPLPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 10') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 10') : 0;
       Decimal OFFPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 11') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 11') : 0;
       Decimal ONEPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 12') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 12') : 0;
       Decimal ONMPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 13') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 13') : 0;
       Decimal ONWPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 14') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 14') : 0;
       Decimal CHEMPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 15') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 15') : 0;
       Decimal REFPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 16') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 16') : 0;
       Decimal AUSPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 17') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 17') : 0;
       Decimal UKPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 18') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 18') : 0;
       Decimal ECANPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 19') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 19') : 0;
       Decimal WCANPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 20') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 20') : 0;
       Decimal UTPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 21') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 21') : 0;
       Decimal PSPGP = PointsPercent.ContainsKey('Team 22') ? PointsPercent.get('Team 22') : 0;

       Decimal PointTotal = (AATTP + AGP + FBP + PHP + STP + WPBCPP + COP + MSP + MSCBP + PPLP + OFFP + ONEP + ONMP + ONWP + CHEMP + REFP + AUSP + UKP + ECANP + WCANP + UTP + PSP);
       Decimal PointGoalTotal = 410000;
       Decimal PointPercentTotal = (PointTotal / PointGoalTotal * 100);

       string emlBody =
       '<html><font size=2 face=Arial>' +     
       '<b><u>Points:</u></b><br/>' + 
       'Team 1:  ' + AATTP.format() + ' / ' + AATTPG.format() + ' / ' + AATTPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 2:  ' + AGP.format() + ' / ' + AGPG.format() + ' / ' + AGPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 3:  ' + FBP.format() + ' / ' + FBPG.format() + ' / ' + FBPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 4:  ' + PHP.format() + ' / ' + PHPG.format() + ' / ' + PHPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 5:  ' + STP.format() + ' / ' + STPG.format() + ' / ' + STPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 6:  ' + WPBCPP.format() + ' / ' + WPBCPPG.format() + ' / ' + WPBCPPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 7:  ' + COP.format() + ' / ' + COPG.format() + ' / ' + COPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 8: ' + MSCBP.format() + ' / ' + MSCBPG.format() + ' / ' + MSCBPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 9:  ' + MSP.format() + ' / ' + MSPG.format() + ' / ' + MSPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 10:  ' + PPLP.format() + ' / ' + PPLPG.format() + ' / ' + PPLPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 11:  ' + OFFP.format() + ' / ' + OFFPG.format() + ' / ' + OFFPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 12:  ' + ONEP.format() + ' / ' + ONEPG.format() + ' / ' + ONEPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 13:  ' + ONMP.format() + ' / ' + ONMPG.format() + ' / ' + ONMPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 14:  ' + ONWP.format() + ' / ' + ONWPG.format() + ' / ' + ONWPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 15:  ' + CHEMP.format() + ' / ' + CHEMPG.format() + ' / ' + CHEMPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 16:  ' + REFP.format() + ' / ' + REFPG.format() + ' / ' + REFPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 17:  ' + AUSP.format() + ' / ' + AUSPG.format() + ' / ' + AUSPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 18:  ' + UKP.format() + ' / ' + UKPG.format() + ' / ' + UKPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 19:  ' + ECANP.format() + ' / ' + ECANPG.format() + ' / ' + ECANPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 20:  ' + WCANP.format() + ' / ' + WCANPG.format() + ' / ' + WCANPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 21:  ' + UTP.format() + ' / ' + UTPG.format() + ' / ' + UTPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       'Team 22:  ' + PSP.format() + ' / ' + PSPG.format() + ' / ' + PSPGP.setScale(0) + '%<br/>' + 
       '<b>TOTAL:  ' + PointTotal.format() + ' / ' + PointGoalTotal.format() + ' / ' + PointPercentTotal.setScale(0) + '%</b><br/>' + 
       '</font></html>';

       new mail = PentathlonMail.sendPentathlonMail(message, emlBody);
    }
}

public class PentathlonMail {
    public string body;

    public static void sendPentathlonMail(string emlbody) {
       body = emlbody;

       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

       mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'email@email.com'});  
       mail.setSubject('Points (TESTING)');
       mail.setUseSignature(false);
       mail.setHtmlBody(body);

       // Send the email
       Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

   }

}
```

Note: above code has not been tested or debugged and is for guidance only.