# How to render Record Types to visual force page?

Tags: visualforce

I have created 2 VF pages and i want to display those VF page according to the record type selection. But it was showing 2 VF pages one by one at a  time. Please any one suggest or modify the below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.RecordTypeId!='012400000009mCCAAY',true,false)}">
        <apex:include pageName="OppVfPage" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.RecordTypeId!='01240000000UWKDAA4',true,false)}">
        <apex:include pageName="LostReason" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like?  You're only including one page here.  We're going to need to see more to understand what's going on.

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.RecordTypeId!='012400000009mCCAAY',true,false)}">
<apex:include pageName="OppVfPage" />
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.RecordTypeId!='01240000000UWKDAA4',true,false)}">
<apex:include pageName="LostReason" />
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 1):

If both of the pages are rendering, it means that both of the `rendered` conditions are evaluating to `true`.  So, in the first case your Opportunity.RecordTypeId is **not** `012400000009mCCAAY` and in the second it's **not** `01240000000UWKDAA4`.

It seems strange to me that you want these outputPanels to render if the RecordTypeIds do **NOT** equal these IDs.  I would start by double-checking that logic.

If that is correct, you need to figure out why the RecordTypeIds do not equal the IDs given.  You can do this by [debugging your code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code) - using `System.debug()` in your controller to find the value of the `Opportunity.RecordTypeId` in both cases.