# Code Coverage not working on tests

Tags: apex, unit-test

So, I did a button linked to an apex class which turns a candidate into an account when a recruiter wants, when I try to deploy it on production it says that I have 72% of test coverage, but when I run the test in my developer console (on sandbox) it doesn't show the lines in blue or red to help me improve the percentage. Please take a look on the codes and help me.

**The Class:**

```
global with sharing class ContratarCandidato{

global ContratarCandidato(){}

@TestVisible
WebService static void gerarContaFromCandidato (Id idCandidato){

    system.Debug(idCandidato);

    List<SFDC_Candidate__c> lstCandidato = new List<SFDC_Candidate__c>([
        SELECT Sobrenome_do_candidato__c, Name, CPF__c, Genero__c, Telefone__c, Celular__c, Email__c, Email_alternativo__c,
               Endereco__c, Bairro__c, Cidade__c, Estado__c, CEP__c, Indicacao_funcionario__c, Id, Origem_da_conta__c
        FROM SFDC_Candidate__c
        WHERE Id = :idCandidato]);            
    system.Debug(lstCandidato);

    Account newAccount= new Account();

    if(lstCandidato[0].Sobrenome_do_candidato__c == null){
        newAccount.LastName = 'N/A';
    }else{
        newAccount.LastName = lstCandidato[0].Sobrenome_do_candidato__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Name== null){
        newAccount.FirstName = 'N/A';
    }else{
        newAccount.FirstName = lstCandidato[0].Name;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].CPF__c== null){
        newAccount.CPF__pc= 'N/A';
    }else{
        newAccount.CPF__pc= lstCandidato[0].CPF__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Genero__c == 'Feminino'){
        newAccount.Salutation = 'Sra.';
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Genero__c == 'Masculino'){
        newAccount.Salutation = 'Sr.';
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Telefone__c != null){
        newAccount.Phone = lstCandidato[0].Telefone__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Celular__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMobilePhone = lstCandidato[0].Celular__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Email__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonEmail = lstCandidato[0].Email__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Endereco__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingStreet = lstCandidato[0].Endereco__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Bairro__c != null){
        newAccount.Bairro_de_correspondencia__pc = lstCandidato[0].Bairro__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Cidade__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingCity = lstCandidato[0].Cidade__c;
    }
    if (lstCandidato[0].Estado__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingState = lstCandidato[0].Estado__c;
    }
    if (lstCandidato[0].CEP__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingPostalCode = lstCandidato[0].CEP__c;
    }
    if (lstCandidato[0].Origem_da_conta__c != null){
        newAccount.AccountSource = lstCandidato[0].Origem_da_conta__c;
    }
    newAccount.Status_da_conta__c = 'Ativa';
    newAccount.Type = 'Colaborador PJ';
    newAccount.Colaborador_RCS__c = true;
    newAccount.RecordTypeId = '012q00000000STyAAM';

    insert newAccount;

    }
}
```

**The Test:**

```
@isTest
public class ContratarCandidatoTest {

static testMethod void gerarContaFromCandidatoTest(){

    SFDC_Candidate__c newCandidato = new SFDC_Candidate__c();        
    newCandidato.Sobrenome_do_candidato__c = 'Class';
    newCandidato.Name = 'Test';
    newCandidato.CPF__c = '980.091.918-22';
    newCandidato.Telefone__c = '(19) 3910-0295';
    newCandidato.Celular__c = '(19) 98940-0982';
    newCandidato.Email__c = 'testclass12@rcs.com.br';
    newCandidato.Email_alternativo__c = 'emailalternativo@rcs.com.br';
    newCandidato.Endereco__c = 'Avenida Andromêda, 885';
    newCandidato.Estado__c = 'São Paulo';
    newCandidato.Bairro__c = 'Alphaville';
    newCandidato.Cidade__c = 'Barueri';

    newCandidato.CEP__c = '86000-000';        
    insert newCandidato;

    newCandidato.Celular__c = '(19) 91234-5678';
    update newCandidato;

    List<SFDC_Candidate__c> lstCandidato = new List<SFDC_Candidate__c>([
        SELECT Sobrenome_do_candidato__c, Name, CPF__c, Telefone__c, Celular__c, Email__c,
               Email_alternativo__c, Endereco__c, Estado__c, Bairro__c, Cidade__c, CEP__c, Genero__c
        FROM SFDC_Candidate__c
        WHERE Name = 'Test'
    ]);

    List<RecordType> newRecordType = new List<RecordType>([
        SELECT Name, Id, SobjectType
        FROM RecordType
        WHERE Name = 'Colaborador RCS'
        AND SObjectType = 'Account']);

    Account newAccount = new Account();        
    if(lstCandidato[0].Sobrenome_do_candidato__c == null){
        newAccount.LastName = 'N/A';
    }else{
        newAccount.LastName = newCandidato.Sobrenome_do_candidato__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Name== null){
        newAccount.FirstName = 'N/A';
    }else{
        newAccount.FirstName = newCandidato.Name;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].CPF__c== null){
        newAccount.CPF__pc= 'N/A';
    }else{
        newAccount.CPF__pc= newCandidato.CPF__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Genero__c == 'Feminino'){
        newAccount.Salutation = 'Sra.';
    }else{
        newAccount.Salutation = 'Sr.';
    }

    if(lstCandidato[0].Telefone__c != null){
        newAccount.Phone = newCandidato.Telefone__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Celular__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMobilePhone = newCandidato.Celular__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Email__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonEmail= newCandidato.Email__c;
    }
    if(lstCandidato[0].Endereco__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingStreet = newCandidato.Endereco__c;
    }
    newAccount.Bairro_de_correspondencia__pc = newCandidato.Bairro__c;
    if(newCandidato.Cidade__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingCity = newCandidato.Cidade__c;
    }
    if (newCandidato.Estado__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingState = newCandidato.Estado__c;
    }
    if (newCandidato.CEP__c != null){
        newAccount.PersonMailingPostalCode = newCandidato.CEP__c;
    }
    newAccount.Status_da_conta__c = 'Ativa';
    newAccount.Type = 'Colaborador PJ';
    newAccount.Colaborador_RCS__c = true;
    newAccount.RecordTypeId = newRecordType[0].Id;
    insert newAccount;


    List<SFDC_Candidate__c> lstCandidato2 = new List<SFDC_Candidate__c>([
        SELECT Name
        FROM SFDC_Candidate__c
        WHERE Name = 'Test'
    ]);
    System.debug(lstCandidato2);

    lstCandidato2[0].Name = 'Teste';
    update lstCandidato2[0];

    List<Account> lstTeste = new List<Account>([
        SELECT Status_da_conta__c, FirstName
        FROM Account
        WHERE FirstName = 'Test'
    ]);
    System.debug(lstTeste);

    lstTeste[0].Status_da_conta__c = 'Inativa';
    update lstTeste[0];
    System.debug(lstTeste);

    delete newCandidato;
    delete newAccount;


}

}
```

Comment: You do not make a single assertion in this test. It has essentially no value even if it does increase your coverage metric.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me as though you're testing for either of the possibilities for 'Genero'. With a method for each, you'd easily increase your coverage.

You need a method for when it's male and another method for when it's female.  You need enough methods in your test class to cover all the `If - Else If` possibilities in your conditional statements. Each one requires a different test method.

Also, make certain you're populating all of the fields that your class uses like `Origem_da_conta__c`. If you don't, those lines won't be covered. You've not done that, thus why you don't have the coverage. Add debug statements nested within your `If` statements you can view in the debug logs to see if the code inside them is being executed.

You might find [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code/36616#36616) helpful to you.

Comment: Did it and got 73% now, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: See edited answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just to show what's happening, I don't think the test class is actually testing the class...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The class is not appearing in the sidebar, IDK why...