# how i can send latest job application with Latest Job then that i get this error : Compile Error:

Tags: apex, trigger

error is
Error: Compile Error: expecting right square bracket, found 'And' at line 48 column 111

```
trigger SendEmailUser on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {

    Set<Id> setResource=new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> setjob=new Set<Id>();
    List<NewJob__c> LatestJob=new List<NewJob__c>();
    for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new){
        if(opp.Status__c == 'new'){
            if(opp.Resource__c != null ){
                setResource.add(opp.Resource__c);
              //  setjob.add(opp.Job__c);
            }
        }
    }

    List<String> lstEmails=new List<String>();
    if(!setResource.isEmpty()){
        List<Resource__c> lstResource= [Select Id,Email__c from Resource__c Where Id IN : setResource];
        if(!lstResource.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Resource__c res:lstResource)
            {
                lstEmails.add(res.Email__c);
            }
        }
    }
   string ljob='';
     if(!setResource.isEmpty()){
    List<NewJob__c> newJoblist=[SELECT Id FROM NewJob__c order by CreatedDate desc limit 1];


        if(!newJoblist.isEmpty())
        {
             for(NewJob__c jobl:newJoblist){
              setjob.add(jobl.id);
      //          ljob=ljob+'https://ap2.salesforce.com/'+jobl.id+'\n';
           }
       }

   }






    String Body='';
    if(!setResource.isEmpty()){
        List<Job_Application__c> Joblist=[SELECT Id FROM Job_Application__c order by CreatedDate desc limit 1  And Id IN(setjob) ];
        if(!Joblist.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Job_Application__c job:Joblist){
                body=body+'https://ap2.salesforce.com/'+job.id+'\n';
               // body=ljob+'https://ap2.salesforce.com/'+job.id+'\n';
            }
        }
    }

    if(!lstEmails.isEmpty()){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(lstEmails);   
        mail.setSubject('Job Alert');  
        mail.setPlainTextBody(Body);
        mail.setHtmlBody(Body);
        Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    }

}
```

Comment: in opportunity object have status and Opportunity fields and Resource field, in Resource   object have id  resource  name and email filed ,In New job object have New job id, name opportunity (lookup),in job application have id,name,Job(lookup) fields

Comment: requirement is when ever new Opportunity is created or updated with status new send mail to the resource mail id with the latest job allocation of latest job of oppurtunity to get url

Answer (score 0):

In SOQL the terms must be in the correct order and follow the syntax listed in [SOQL SELECT Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm). So to fix the compile error your query should be:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Job_Application__c
WHERE Id IN :setjob
ORDER BY CreatedDate desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'setjob' at line 48 column 88

Comment: @user25465 Woops missed the `:` needed for bind variables and the () should not be there. I've changed it.

Comment: When LInk Is not send in mail...only mail is send to resource mail but in that no link

Comment: @user25465 I suggest you spend some time learning how to add debug logging so you can figure it out yourself. See e.g. [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code).