# Batch apex execute method not invoked

Tags: apex, batch

I copied this code from SF docs and modified it to my requirement:

```
global class OwnerReassignment implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

        global final string query;
        global final string email;

        /*global OwnerReassignment (String q, String e){
                 query=q; 
                 email=e; 
        }*/

        global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }

        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
            List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
            Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;
            for(sObject s : scope){
                Lead a = (Lead)s;
                a.setOptions(dmo);
                a.Notes__c='Test Execute Batch Class';
                leads.add(a);
            }
            update leads;
        }

        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {email});
            mail.setReplyTo('batch@acme.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Batch Processing');
            mail.setSubject('Batch Process Completed');
            mail.setPlainTextBody('Batch Process has completed');

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
    }
```

When I execute this Code it is not updating record.

```
OwnerReassignment reassign = new OwnerReassignment();
reassign.query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE OwnerId = \'00Q2000000nCIJo\'';
reassign.email='abc@abc.com';
ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(reassign);
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

Comment: Have you created a test class for this? You'll learn a great deal from using Test Driven Development. I also highly recommend [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code/36616#36616). I don't see any debug statements in your code to help you figure out the source of your problem.

Comment: ProTip: don't actually make this global unless you intend put it in a managed package **AND** intend to call it from _outside_ that package. I don't understand why SFDC's examples so frequently show globals, given how strict they are about actually using them.

Comment: In Salesforce example template, they use `global` modifier. So, anyone who copying the code their will have the `global` modifier. Regardless of why it should `global`. Batches should not use `global` unless it is required.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that Lead has some records or not. Debugging is good way to find out the problem.

```
OwnerReassignment reassign = new OwnerReassignment();

reassign.query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE OwnerId = \'00Q2000000nCIJo\'';
// Check
List<Lead> leadList = Database.query(reassign.query);
System.debug(' List Size ' +leadList.size());
// Remove above two lines if it works.

reassign.email='abc@abc.com';
ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(reassign);
```

In addition this will also work:-

```
      for(Lead a : (List<Lead>)scope)
      {
            a.setOptions(dmo);
            a.Notes__c='Test Execute Batch Class';
      }

      update scope;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashwani and @crmprogdev!!
I got it working!!