# Many unnested loops cause 'Apex CPU time limit exceeded'

Tags: unit-test, loop, nested

I'm not sure what's happening, but all what I'm trying to do is to write a simple test class which inserting a lot of records. However, my records are related in different relations.

---

My test class is:

```
@isTest
private class A800ExpiredClientReportV2Test {

static testMethod void reportingExpiredClientTest() {
    Integer bulkDataValue = 200;
    Client__c randomClient = new Client__c(Name__c = 'MAZEN', Phone__c='0000');
    insert randomClient;

    // Targeting     ->    First SOQL statment, attribut name: quotList
    // SELECT ID, To__c, Quotation_Total__c, Time_Left__c, Client_Name__c, Client__c, Name, Phone__c, Confirm_Renewal__c 
    //       FROM Quotation__c WHERE 
    // (Expiry_Notification_1__c = true AND Confirm_Renewal__c = false AND Stored_Inventory_Items__c > 0 AND Paid_Invoices__c >0)
    //       OR 
    // (Expiry_Notification_1__c = true AND Subsequent_Quotation__c != null AND Paid_Invoices__c >0)
    //       ORDER BY To__c
    Date nowDay = Date.Today();
    List<Quotation__c> quotList_tst = new List<Quotation__c>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i++){
        if(math.mod(i, 2) == 0){
            // (Expiry_Notification_1__c = true AND Confirm_Renewal__c = false AND Stored_Inventory_Items__c > 0 AND Paid_Invoices__c > 0)
            quotList_tst.add(new Quotation__c(Client__c = randomClient.Id, Duration_Months__c = 1, From__c = nowDay.addDays(10), Confirm_Renewal__c = false));
        } else {
            // (Expiry_Notification_1__c = true AND Subsequent_Quotation__c != null AND Paid_Invoices__c >0)
            quotList_tst.add(new Quotation__c(Client__c = randomClient.Id, Duration_Months__c = 1, From__c = nowDay.addDays(10), Subsequent_Quotation__c = quotList_tst[i-1].Id));
        }
    }
    insert quotList_tst;

    // Process: Stored_Inventory_Items__c > 0
    List<Inventory_Sheet__c> quotList_tst_InventorySheet = new List<Inventory_Sheet__c>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i++){
        if(math.mod(i, 2) == 0){
            quotList_tst_InventorySheet.add(new Inventory_Sheet__c(Quotation__c = quotList_tst[i].Id));
        }
    }
    insert quotList_tst_InventorySheet;

    List<Inventory_Line_Item__c> quotList_tst_InventorySheet_InventeryItem = new List<Inventory_Line_Item__c>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i+2){
        //if(math.mod(i, 2) == 0){
        quotList_tst_InventorySheet_InventeryItem.add(new Inventory_Line_Item__c(Inventory_Sheet__c = quotList_tst_InventorySheet[i].Id, Code_Number__c = 'any Code', Entry_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2016,12,16))); // Line #41
        //}
    }
    insert quotList_tst_InventorySheet_InventeryItem;
    // END Process


    // Process: Paid_Invoices__c > 0
    List<Invoice__c> paidInvoicesFor_quotList_tst = new List<Invoice__c>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i++){
        paidInvoicesFor_quotList_tst.add(new Invoice__c(Quotation__c = quotList_tst[i].Id, Status__c = 'Paid', Method_of_Payment__c = 'Cash', Payment_Date__c = Date.Today()));
    }
    insert paidInvoicesFor_quotList_tst;
    // END Process

    Test.startTest();
        A800ExpiredClientReportV2 expiredClientReport = new A800ExpiredClientReportV2();
    Test.stopTest();

    Set<Id> expectedRecordIds_quotList = new Map<Id, SObject>(quotList_tst).keySet();
    Set<Id> actualIds_quotList = new Map<Id, SObject>(expiredClientReport.quotList).keySet();
    system.assert(expectedRecordIds_quotList.size() == bulkDataValue);
    system.assert(actualIds_quotList.size() == bulkDataValue);
    system.assertEquals(expectedRecordIds_quotList, actualIds_quotList);
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is: Inserting one `Inventory_Line_Item__c` record, so its `Inventory_Sheet__c` parent record updates its `Stored_Items__c` field [Roll-Up Summary (`COUNT Inventory Item`)], so the field `Stored_Inventory_Items__c` in `Quotation__c` object will have a value of more than 0, which what I need for my SOQL statement.
When I click run, the following error message coming up:

> System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded 
>   Class.A800ExpiredClientReportV2Test.reportingExpiredClientTest: line
>   41, column 1

I referred to **Line 41** as a comment in my code.
I looked up about this error, and generally all answers talking about nested loops, but I'm not sure if there are any nested loops in my code behind the scene. :/

Answer (score 7):

Your loop:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i+2){
```

never terminates hence you hit the CPU limit.

You probably meant something like:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i += 2){
```

Comment: Fine catch there! I was going to wax philosophical about checking for inefficient and tightly interwoven triggers, and moving repeated function calls like `nowDate.addDays(10)` outside of loops.

Comment: @DerekF Yeah, rare to see a case where a governor limit is doing 100% good. My first thought was bad trigger logic.

Comment: Now, it's giving me this: `System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 100

Class.A800ExpiredClientReportV2Test.reportingExpiredClientTest: line 41, column 1`. It seems that this loop never stops :/ !!

Comment: I even tried to leave it `for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i ++){` and un-comment the `if(math.mod(i, 2) == 0)` statement below it, but same error. @KeithC

Comment: @MAZux See [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code).