# Scheduled job threw unhandled exception

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, exception

new here... =)
But hopefully, with your help, I can become someone who can help others.

in any case... before that will happen. I will probably ask for your help!

This apex class"'Update Score Cards'", works nicely. Yet every day I receive this email:

> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization:
>   00580000003IjlO/00D3000000077wK
>
> Scheduled job 'Update Score Cards' threw unhandled exception.
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object
>
> Class.ScoreCardGenerator.processScoreCards: line 186, column 1
>   Class.ScoreCardScheduler.execute: line 6, column 1

Should I keep ignoring it? Or should I find out where and what is the issue?

Comment: You should find out and fix this. Not a big task. Got to this class and line number and put null check and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

An exception being thrown means any code after that exception is thrown is not run and normally also means that any database changes will be thrown away (the transaction will be rolled back). So some work is not being done that should be being done so you should track this error down and fix it.

Examine line 186 of this class and think about any reason why a variable in that line would not have been set or would have been set to `null`. The problem may occur earlier in the code; you can use `System.debug` statements to output values - see [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code)