# Can anyone confirm if the before delete with trigger.old is not firing/working on attachments

Tags: trigger

Can anyone confirm if the before delete with trigger.old is not firing/working on attachments. I do have a before trigger which is not firing.

```
trigger deletionPrevention on Attachment (before delete) 
{
  for ( Attachment currAtt : trigger.old ) { 
    if ( !( isAllowed(currAtt, theUser, allowedUsers) ) ) {..} 
  }
}
```

Comment: As you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm), your trigger is supposed to be fired.

Comment: Your code seems correct, are you sure the trigger is active?

Comment: Best place is to look [`debug logs`](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code)!

Comment: your trigger looks good.. whats in the if condition.. ? may be if condition is evaluated as false and thereby no logic is performed..

Comment: trigger is active, condition: if ( !( isAllowed(currAtt, theUser, allowedUsers) ) )  debuglog didnt show any logs