# How to see the debug result

Tags: apex, debugging

I am using Dev Console Go to Debug->Open execute Anonymous window->Paste my line of code that I want to Debug but the window shows error :Line: 1, Column: 1

> Enclosing type for global properties in apex classes must be declared as global

My apex:

```
global with sharing class DynamicController{
    global list<Dynamic__c> theresult{get;set;}
    global list<Dynamic__c> dynamicresult{get;set;}
    global String i{get;set;}
    global Apexpages.StandardSetController Accountserctrl{get;set;}

    global DynamicController(){
        String query = 'select name,Dynamic_content__c,Dynamic_image__c,Dynamic_release_time__c from Dynamic__c order by Dynamic_release_time__c';
        Dynamic__c a = [select id,Dynamic_image__c from Dynamic__c limit 1];
        String url = a.Dynamic_image__c.substringBetween('<img', 'img>');
        i = url.substringBetween('src="','"');
        System.debug(i);
        theresult = Database.query(query);
        Accountserctrl = new Apexpages.StandardSetController(theresult);
        dynamicresult = Accountserctrl.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have changed your question to something *completely* different after receiving a few answers (which apparently [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)). You would make it easier to help you in the long run if you instead [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) which you found most helpful and ask a new question about this completely separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Dev Console Go to Debug->Open execute Anonymous window->Paste your line of code that you want to Debug and execute you can find the result at Logs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article a useful primer:

> ### [Set Up Debug Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=0)
>
> To activate debug logging for users, Apex classes, and Apex triggers, configure trace flags and debug levels in the Developer Console or in Setup. Each trace flag includes a debug level, start time, end time, and log type. The trace flag’s log type specifies the entity you’re tracing.
>
> ...
>
> #### Configure Trace Flags in the Developer Console
>
> To configure trace flags and debug levels from the Developer Console, click Debug | Change Log Levels. Then complete these actions.
>
> - To create a trace flag, click Add.
> - To edit an existing trace flag’s duration, double-click its start or end time.
> - To change a trace flag’s debug level, click Add/Change in the Debug Level Action column. You can then edit your existing debug levels, create or delete a debug level, and assign a debug level to your trace flag. Deleting a debug level deletes all trace flags that use it.
>
> #### Create Trace Flags in Setup
>
> 1. From Setup, enter Debug Logs in the Quick Find box, then click Debug Logs.
> 2. Click New.
> 3. Select the entity to trace, the time period during which you want to collect logs, and a debug level. A debug level is a set of log levels for debug log categories: Database, Workflow, Validation, and so on. You can reuse debug levels across your trace flags.

See also: [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/36582/2995)