# Attempt to dereference null object error callout in salesforce

Tags: apex, callout, xml

I am  getting attempt to de-reference null object error the below callouts.

class1:

```
public class ProcessImgCallout {

    @future (callout=true)

    public static void SendImage(ID id) {
        system.debug('hello Mahesh '+id);

        String endPointURL = 'https://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processBusinessCard?exportformat=xml';
        String userName = '';// i removed username for security puropse
        String password = '';//i removed password for security puropse
        ContentVersion co = [Select id,pathOnClient,title,versionData  from ContentVersion where id =:id];
        Blob img =co.versionData;

        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userName + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
           EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        Httprequest request = new HttpRequest();
        Http http = new Http();

        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint(endPointURL);
        request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        request.setTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);

        request.setBodyAsBlob(img);          

        HttpResponse res = http.send(request);  

        System.debug('responseBody: '+res.getBody());

        Dom.Document docx = new Dom.Document();
        //docx.load(responseUrl2);
        system.debug('@@@'+res.getbody());
        docx.load(res.getbody()); 
        //system.debug('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ '+doc);
        String taskId = docx.getRootElement().getChildElement('task', null).getAttribute('id', null);
        system.debug(taskId);
        gettaskStatus.GetStatus(taskId);
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class gettaskStatus {

    public static void GetStatus(String id){
        system.debug('hello mahesh i am with task id to get status'+id);
        //String taskid=id;


        String endPointURL = 'http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/getTaskStatus?taskId='+id;
        system.debug(endPointURL);
        String userName = '';//i removed username for security puropse
        String password = '';//i removed password for security puropse
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userName + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
            EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        Httprequest req = new HttpRequest();
        Http ht = new Http();

        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(endPointURL);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);
        //req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');



        HttpResponse resp = ht.send(req);  

        System.debug('responseBody: to download url '+resp.getBody());

        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        //docx.load(responseUrl2);
        system.debug('@@@'+resp.getbody());
        doc.load(resp.getbody()); 
        //system.debug('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ '+doc);
        String resulturl = doc.getRootElement().getChildElement('task', null).getAttribute('resultUrl', null);
        system.debug(resulturl);
        GetLeadfromUrl.GetDownloadUrl(resulturl);

    }

}
```

I am getting attempt to de-reference null object error in the second class can anyone please help me , how to fix this?

```
public class GetLeadfromUrl {
    public static void GetDownloadUrl(String url) { 
        String ROOT_TAG = 'ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd';; 
        // system.debug(url);
        String downloadurl=url;
        String newUrl=downloadurl.remove('amp;');
        system.debug(newUrl); 
        String endPointURL =newUrl; 

        // ??
    }
}
```

Comment: Few times it is working fine, but most of the time it is giving error has attempt to deference null objcet

Comment: You need to identify the line number the problem occurs at - see e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code for how to get that information - and then consider what null value on that line is causing the problem.

Comment: Class.GetLeadfromUrl.GetDownloadUrl: line 7, column 1
Class.gettaskStatus.GetStatus: line 37, column 1
Class.ProcessImgCallout.SendImage: line 39, column 1
16:10:36.29 (526284477)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.GetLeadfromUrl.GetDownloadUrl: line 7, column 1
Class.gettaskStatus.GetStatus: line 37, column 1
Class.ProcessImgCallout.SendImage: line 39, column 1
16:10:36.526 (526290597)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
16:10:36.526 (526290597)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|

Comment: Check line 7 of GetLeadfromUrl.GetDownloadUrl which is where the problem originates.

Comment: public class GetLeadfromUrl {
    
     public static void GetDownloadUrl(String url){
         String ROOT_TAG = 'http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd';
       // system.debug(url);
        String downloadurl=url;
         String newUrl=downloadurl.remove('amp;');
          system.debug(newUrl);
         
         String endPointURL =newUrl;

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the parameter being passed into `GetLeadfromUrl.GetDownloadUrl(String url)` is null.

The first thing you can do is guard against this as early as possible in the method.

E.g.

```
public class GetLeadfromUrl {
    public static void GetDownloadUrl(string url) { 
        System.assertNotEquals(null, url, 'url parameter is required');
        String ROOT_TAG = 'ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd';
    }
}
```

Because the url parameter is null we can imply that `resulturl` is also null.

```
String resulturl = doc.getRootElement().getChildElement('task', null).getAttribute('resultUrl', null);
```

Check your debug logs that the XML you are trying to parse matches your expectations.

Comment: Spot on. Except you should never validate live code with assertions! The resulting exception is uncatchable.

Comment: True. Very handy for debugging though if you intentionally want to break out past any exception handling and see the direct stack trace. :)

Comment: Indeed. Useful for debugging.