# Test Class fail

Tags: apex, trigger, error

UPDATE - 
I have found that the trigger I was trying to deploy is probably the cause of the other issues. This trigger is to count all opps associated to an account and update the account field "Number of Opportunities". Is there a better way to write this so I don't get the error of too many SOQL queries?

```
trigger CountOpps on Opportunity ( after insert, after update) {

    Opportunity [] Opps;

        Opps = Trigger.new;

    // get list of accounts
    Set<ID> acctIds = new Set<ID>();
    for (Opportunity opp : Opps) {
        if (opp.Stage_Calc__c != null)
            acctIds.add(opp.AccountId);
    }

    Map<ID, Opportunity> OppsForAccounts = new Map<ID, Opportunity>([select Id
                                                            ,AccountId
                                                            from Opportunity
                                                            ]);

    Map<ID, Account> acctsToUpdate = new Map<ID, Account>([select Id
                                                                 ,Number_of_Opps__c
                                                                  from Account
                                                                  where Id in :acctIds]);

    for (Account acct : acctsToUpdate.values()) {
        Set<ID> OppIds = new Set<ID>();
        for (Opportunity opp : OppsForAccounts.values()) {
            if (opp.AccountId == acct.Id)
                OppIds.add(opp.Id);
        }
        if (acct.Number_of_Opps__c != OppIds.size())
            acct.Number_of_Opps__c = OppIds.size();
    }

    update acctsToUpdate.values();
}
```

I recently had this test class start to fail, I did not write this class it was written by a partner who integrated SF and NetSuite. The test is far more advanced than I can write at this time. The error I am getting is:

> **System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a10f0000000QhRhAAK; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   celigoUpdateSalesOrder: execution of BeforeDelete caused by:
>   System.Exception: Too many SOQL queries: 101
>   Trigger.fulfillmentcontactcreatedopp: line 22, column 1**
>   **Stacktrace: Class.CeligoTestTriggers.testTrigger: line 280, column 1**

Here are both the test class that is failing and the referenced trigger (bolded lines)

```
Test Class
@isTest
private class CeligoTestTriggers {
    static testMethod void testAccountsAndContacts (){
        Test.startTest();

        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'testAccA';
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(a);
        accounts.add(a);

        Account a4 = new Account();
        a4.Name = 'testAccB';
        a4.NetSuite_Pull__c = true;
         //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(a4);
        accounts.add(a4);

        Account a3 = new Account();
        a3.Name = 'testAccD';
        a3.NetSuite_Id__c = '-1';
        a3.NetSuite_Locked__c = false;
         //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(a3);
        accounts.add(a3);

        Account a5 = new Account();
        a5.Name = 'testAccE';
        a5.NetSuite_Id__c = '-1';
        a5.Celigo_Update__c = true;
         //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(a5);
        accounts.add(a5);

        insert accounts;

        Account actual = [SELECT id,Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Account where id = :a.id];
        System.assert(actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(actual.NS_Sync__c == null);

        actual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Account where id = :a3.id];
        System.assert(actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(actual.NS_Sync__c == null);

        actual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Account where id = :a4.id];
        System.assert(actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(actual.NS_Sync__c == null);


        //Test contacts 

        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.LastName = 'testConA';
        //fill contact fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(c);
        contacts.add(c);

        Contact c2 = new Contact();
        c2.LastName = 'testConB';
        c2.Celigo_Update__c = true;
         //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(c2);
        contacts.add(c2);

        Contact c3 = new Contact();
        c3.LastName = 'testConC';
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(c3);
        c3.AccountId = actual.Id;
        contacts.add(c3);

        insert contacts;
        Contact cActual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Contact where id = :c.id];
        System.assert(actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(actual.NS_Sync__c == null);

        cActual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Contact where id = :c2.id];
        System.assert(actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(actual.NS_Sync__c == null);

        Contact c3Actual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Contact where id = :c3.id];
        System.assert(c3Actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(c3Actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(c3Actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(c3Actual.NS_Sync__c == null);

        List<Contact> updateContact = new List<Contact>();
        c2.LastName = 'testConC';
        updateContact.add(c2);

        c3.Celigo_Update__c = true;
        updateContact.add(c3);

        update updateContact;
        cActual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Contact where id = :c2.id];
        System.assert(actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(actual.NS_Sync__c == null);

        c3Actual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Update__c, NetSuite_Id__c, NetSuite_Locked__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Contact where id = :c3.id];
        System.assert(c3Actual.Celigo_Update__c == false);
        System.assert(c3Actual.NetSuite_Id__c == null);
        System.assert(c3Actual.NetSuite_Locked__c  == false);
        System.assert(c3Actual.NS_Sync__c == null);

        c3.Celigo_Update__c = false;
        c3.AccountId = null;
        c3.NetSuite_Id__c = '-1';
        update c3;

        Test.stopTest();
    }

   static testMethod void testTrigger () {
        Test.startTest();
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'testAccA';
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        insert a;

        List<Product2> products = new List<Product2>();
        Product2 p = new product2(name='Test Product');
         //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(p);
        products.add(p);

        Product2 p2 = new product2(name='Test Product2');
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(p2);
        products.add(p2);

        insert products;

        System.debug('Success p: ' + p.ID);

        Pricebook2 pb = new pricebook2(name='test pricebook');
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(pb);
        insert pb; 

        System.debug('Success pb: ' + pb.ID);

        Pricebook2 stdPb = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true limit 1];
        System.debug('Success stdPb: ' + stdPb.ID);

        List<PricebookEntry> entryList = new List<PricebookEntry>();

        PricebookEntry pbeS = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id = stdPb.id, product2id = p.id, unitprice=100.0, isActive=true);
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(pbeS);
        entryList.add(pbeS);

        PricebookEntry pbeS2 = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id = stdPb.id, product2id = p2.id, unitprice=100.0, isActive=true);
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(pbeS2);
        entryList.add(pbeS2);

        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id=pb.id, product2id=p.id, unitprice=100.0, isActive=true);
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(pbe);
        entryList.add(pbe);

        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id=pb.id, product2id=p2.id, unitprice=100.0, isActive=true);
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(pbe2);
        entryList.add(pbe2);

        insert entryList;
        System.debug('Success pbeS: ' + pbeS.ID);

        Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
        o.Name = 'test';
        o.AccountId = a.Id;
        o.StageName = 'Prospecting';
        o.CloseDate = Date.today();
        o.A_vs_B__c = 'A Lead';
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(o);
        insert o;
        Opportunity oActual = [SELECT id, StageName, Send_to_NetSuite__c, Generate_Estimate__c, Generate_Sales_Order__c, NS_Sync__c
                   FROM Opportunity where id = :o.id];
        System.assert(oActual.Send_to_NetSuite__c == true);
        System.assert(oActual.Generate_Estimate__c == false);
        System.assert(oActual.Generate_Sales_Order__c  == false);
        System.assert(oActual.NS_Sync__c == null);
        System.assert(oActual.StageName == 'Prospecting');

        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(opportunityid=o.id, UnitPrice=100, quantity=1, pricebookentryid=pbe.Id);    
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(oli);
        insert oli;

        OpportunityLineItem oliActual = [SELECT id, UnitPrice, quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem where id = :oli.id];
        oli.Quantity = 2;
        update oliActual;

        NetSuite_Estimate__c estimate = new NetSuite_Estimate__c();
        estimate.Name = 'test';
        estimate.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(estimate);
        insert estimate;
        oActual = [SELECT id, Celigo_Sync_Helper__c
                   FROM Opportunity where id = :o.id];
        System.assert(oActual.Celigo_Sync_Helper__c == true);

        NetSuite_Estimate__c estimate2 = new NetSuite_Estimate__c();
        estimate2.Name = 'test2';
        estimate2.Opportunity__c = null;
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(estimate2);
        insert estimate2;

        NetSuite_Sales_Order__c order = new NetSuite_Sales_Order__c();
        order.Name = 'test';
        order.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
        //update Opportunity and fill its fields 
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(o, true);
        update o;
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(order);
        insert order;
        oActual = [SELECT id, StageName, StageNameState__c
                   FROM Opportunity where id = :o.id];
        //get the setting for the closed stage
        celigo_connector__c cs = celigo_connector__c.getInstance('Opportunity Closed Stage');
        String closedStage = (cs!=null)?cs.value__c:'Closed Won';
        System.assert(oActual.StageName == closedStage);
        System.assert(oActual.StageNameState__c == 'Prospecting');

        List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c> orderList = new List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c>();

        NetSuite_Sales_Order__c so = new NetSuite_Sales_Order__c();
        so.Name = 'testSO';
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(so);
        orderList.add(so);

        NetSuite_Sales_Order__c so2 = new NetSuite_Sales_Order__c();
        so2.Name = 'test';
        so2.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
        //fill fields defined in the setting
        CeligoTestHelper.fillSobject(so2);
        orderList.add(so2);

        insert orderList;
        oActual = [SELECT id, StageName, StageNameState__c
                   FROM Opportunity where id = :o.id];
        System.assert(oActual.StageName == closedStage );
        System.assert(oActual.StageNameState__c == 'Prospecting');

        delete so2;

        ***oActual = [SELECT id, StageName, StageNameState__c
                   FROM Opportunity where id = :o.id];
        System.assert(oActual.StageName == closedStage);
        System.assert(oActual.StageNameState__c == 'Prospecting');***

        delete order;
        oActual = [SELECT id, StageName, StageNameState__c
                   FROM Opportunity where id = :o.id];
        System.assert(oActual.StageName == 'Prospecting');
        System.assert(oActual.StageNameState__c == null);

        CeligoAccountSyncPoller casp = new CeligoAccountSyncPoller();
        casp.getMessage();
        casp.setShowLoader(true);
        casp.getShowLoader();
        casp.getOpportunityById(o.Id);
        casp.getAccountById(a.Id);
        casp.redirect('home/home.jsp');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', a.Id);
        casp.checkSyncStatus();

        CeligoAccountSyncPoller casp3 = new CeligoAccountSyncPoller();
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', a.Id);
        casp3.checkSyncStatus();

        CeligoAccountSyncPoller casp2 = new CeligoAccountSyncPoller();
        casp2.checkSyncStatus();  

        a.NetSuite_Pull__c = false;
        update a;

        casp2.checkSyncStatus();    

        CeligoQuoteSyncPoller cqsp = new CeligoQuoteSyncPoller();
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', o.Id);
        cqsp.getMessage();
        cqsp.setShowLoader(true);
        cqsp.getShowLoader();
        cqsp.getOpportunityById(o.Id);
        cqsp.getAccountById(a.Id);
        cqsp.redirect('home/home.jsp');
        cqsp.checkSyncStatus(); 

        o.Send_to_NetSuite__c = false;
        o.NS_Sync__c = 'test';
        update o;

        cqsp.checkSyncStatus();

        CeligoSalesOrderSyncPoller csosp = new CeligoSalesOrderSyncPoller();
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', o.Id);
        csosp.checkSyncStatus();
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', null);
        csosp.checkSyncStatus();

        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', o.Id);
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('opp_id', o.Id);
        o.Send_to_NetSuite__c = false;
        o.Celigo_Sync_Helper__c = true;
        o.NS_Sync__c = null;
        update o;

        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', o.Id);
        csosp.checkSyncStatus();
        cqsp.checkSyncStatus();

        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('whence', 'test_xyz');
        csosp.checkSyncStatus();

        csosp.getErrorMessage();
        csosp.getMessage();

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Part that fails:
            ***oActual = [SELECT id, StageName, StageNameState__c
                       FROM Opportunity where id = :o.id];
            System.assert(oActual.StageName == closedStage);
            System.assert(oActual.StageNameState__c == 'Prospecting');***

Trigger

```
trigger fulfillmentcontactcreatedopp on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsToCheckMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new) {

        if(opp.Stage_Calc__c >= 5 ){ 

            if(trigger.isInsert || 
               trigger.isUpdate && trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != opp.StageName)
                oppsToCheckMap.put(opp.Id, opp);
            }
    ***List<AggregateResult> result = [
             select OpportunityId, count(Id)
             from OpportunityContactRole
             where (Role = 'Fulfillment') and
                    OpportunityId in :oppsToCheckMap.keySet() group by OpportunityId];***
    for(AggregateResult aggCount : result) {

        if(aggCount.get('expr0') == 0) {

            Id oppId = (Id)aggCount.get('OpportunityId');
            Opportunity oppo = oppsToCheckMap.get(oppId);

        }
       Integer fulcount = Integer.valueOf(aggCount.get('expr0'));

        opp.Number_of_Fulfillment_Contacts__c = fulcount;
    }
    }
}
```

Line that is referenced:
        ***List< AggregateResult> result = [
                 select OpportunityId, count(Id)
                 from OpportunityContactRole
                 where (Role = 'Fulfillment') and
                        OpportunityId in :oppsToCheckMap.keySet() group by OpportunityId];***

Netsuite_Sales_Order__c Trigger

```
trigger celigoUpdateSalesOrder on NetSuite_Sales_Order__c (before insert, before update, before delete) {

    if (System.Trigger.new != null) {
        List<Id> opIds = new List<Id>();
        for(NetSuite_Sales_Order__c order: System.Trigger.new) {
            if (order.Opportunity__c == null)
                continue;
            opIds.add(order.Opportunity__c);
        }
        List<Opportunity> ops = [select id, StageName, StageNameState__c from Opportunity where Id IN :opIds];
        celigo_connector__c cs = celigo_connector__c.getInstance('Opportunity Closed Stage');
        String closedStage = (cs!=null)?cs.value__c:'Closed Won';
        for (Opportunity o : ops){
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                if (o.StageNameState__c == null) {
                    o.StageNameState__c = o.StageName;
                    o.StageName = closedStage;
                }
            }
            o.Celigo_Sync_Helper__c = true;
            update o;
        }
    }

    if (Trigger.isDelete && System.Trigger.old != null) {
        List<Id> opIds = new List<Id>();
        for (NetSuite_Sales_Order__c order: System.Trigger.old) {
            if (order.Opportunity__c == null)
                continue;
            opIds.add(order.Opportunity__c);
        }

        List<Opportunity> ops = [select id, StageName, StageNameState__c from Opportunity where Id IN :opIds];
        List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c> tOrders = [select id, Opportunity__c from NetSuite_Sales_Order__c where Opportunity__c IN :opIds];
        Map<Id,List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c>> m = new Map<Id,List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c>>();
        for(NetSuite_Sales_Order__c order : tOrders){
            if(m.get(order.Opportunity__c) == null)
                m.put(order.Opportunity__c, new NetSuite_Sales_Order__c[]{order});
            else{
                List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c> temp = m.get(order.Opportunity__c);
                temp.add(order);
            }   
        }
        Set<Id> keys = m.keySet();

        for(Id i : keys){
            List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c> temp = m.get(i);
            Opportunity op;
            for(Opportunity tempOp : ops){
                if(tempOp.Id == i){
                    op = tempOp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(temp.size() > 1)
                continue;
            if(op.StageNameState__c == null)
                continue;
            op.StageName = op.StageNameState__c;
            op.StageNameState__c = null;
            update op;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that you are doing a query inside of a loop.  Extract it from the loop and use a Map to grab associated values instead.  Someone else might give you a more detailed response.

Comment: Your error message describes a problem with the `delete order;` operation happening on line 280 and points to the `before delete` behavior. Can you edit this question and post the `before delete` trigger code on the `NetSuite_Sales_Order__c` object? I suspect that there is an `update` statement in a loop on each of the items in the delete trigger.

Comment: Added the trigger

Comment: Looks like the Celigotesttrigger class fails at this line:  **a4.Name = 'testAccB';**

Comment: @Merry you do not need a trigger to count the number of opportunities under an account. This can be performed without any code at all, using a summary roll up field on the Account.

Comment: DOH! Well, Thanks. Should I mark this as answered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Exception: Too many SOQL queries: 101](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/system-exception-too-many-soql-queries-101)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a commented rewrite of that trigger which does not execute the `aggregateResult` query within the loop context of the `Trigger.new` collection.

Additionally, there's some code in both of your triggers which don't actually do anything as written.

```
trigger fulfillmentcontactcreatedopp on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsToCheckMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    // collect the ID values of the opportunities with a stage calc value of 5 or more
    // if it is an update, the stage name must have changed
    for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new) {

        if (opp.Stage_Calc__c >= 5 ) { 

            if (trigger.isInsert || 
                trigger.isUpdate && trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != opp.StageName) {
                    oppsToCheckMap.put(opp.Id, opp);
            }
        }
    }

    // get an aggregate count of contact roles per opportunity in the fulfillment role
    List<AggregateResult> result = [SELECT OpportunityId
                                        , count(Id)
                                    FROM OpportunityContactRole
                                    WHERE (Role = 'Fulfillment')
                                        AND OpportunityId IN :oppsToCheckMap.keySet()
                                    GROUP BY OpportunityId];

    // iterate the results and set the number of fulfillment contacts on the opportunity
    for (AggregateResult aggCount : result) {

        /* this block of code isn't actually doing anything */
        if (aggCount.get('expr0') == 0) {

            Id oppId = (Id)aggCount.get('OpportunityId');
            Opportunity oppo = oppsToCheckMap.get(oppId);

        }
        /* this block of code isn't actually doing anything */

        // get the opportunity from the incoming map and update the value of the fulfillment contacts field
        Id oppId = (Id)aggCount.get('OpportunityId');
        Opportunity opp = Trigger.newMap.get(oppId);

        if (opp != null) {
            Integer fulcount = Integer.valueOf(aggCount.get('expr0'));
            opp.Number_of_Fulfillment_Contacts__c = fulcount;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

Here is the updated trigger code for the `NetSuite_Sales_Order__c` object with the Opportunity `update` statements removed from the loops. I also reformatted it for my own sanity and changed some of the odd checks for `Trigger.new` and `Trigger.old` in the `if` statements.

```
trigger celigoUpdateSalesOrder on NetSuite_Sales_Order__c (before insert, before update, before delete) {

    List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        List<Id> opIds = new List<Id>();
        for (NetSuite_Sales_Order__c order : Trigger.new) {
            if (order.Opportunity__c == null) {
                continue;
            }
            opIds.add(order.Opportunity__c);
        }

        List<Opportunity> ops = [SELECT Id
                                        , StageName
                                        , StageNameState__c
                                    FROM Opportunity
                                    WHERE Id IN :opIds];

        celigo_connector__c cs = celigo_connector__c.getInstance('Opportunity Closed Stage');
        String closedStage = (cs!=null) ? cs.value__c : 'Closed Won';

        for (Opportunity o : ops) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                if (o.StageNameState__c == null) {
                    o.StageNameState__c = o.StageName;
                    o.StageName = closedStage;
                }
            }
            o.Celigo_Sync_Helper__c = true;

            // add to the list for update later
            opportunitiesToUpdate.add(o);

        }
    }

    if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        List<Id> opIds = new List<Id>();
        for (NetSuite_Sales_Order__c order : Trigger.old) {
            if (order.Opportunity__c == null) {
                continue;
            }
            opIds.add(order.Opportunity__c);
        }

        List<Opportunity> ops = [SELECT Id
                                        , StageName
                                        , StageNameState__c
                                    FROM Opportunity
                                    WHERE Id IN :opIds];

        List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c> tOrders = [SELECT Id
                                                        , Opportunity__c
                                                    FROM NetSuite_Sales_Order__c
                                                    WHERE Opportunity__c IN :opIds];

        Map<Id, List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c>> m = new Map<Id, List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c>>();

        for (NetSuite_Sales_Order__c order : tOrders) {
            if (m.get(order.Opportunity__c) == null) {
                m.put(order.Opportunity__c, new NetSuite_Sales_Order__c[]{ order });
            }
            else {
                /* this code block doesn't do anything */
                List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c> temp = m.get(order.Opportunity__c);
                temp.add(order);
                /* this code block doesn't do anything */
            }   
        }

        Set<Id> keys = m.keySet();

        for (Id i : keys) {
            List<NetSuite_Sales_Order__c> temp = m.get(i);
            Opportunity op;
            for (Opportunity tempOp : ops) {
                if (tempOp.Id == i) {
                    op = tempOp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (temp.size() > 1) {
                continue;
            }

            if (op.StageNameState__c == null) {
                continue;
            }

            op.StageName = op.StageNameState__c;
            op.StageNameState__c = null;

            // add to the list for update later
            opportunitiesToUpdate.add(op);
        }
    }

    // if we've got opportunities to update, do it
    if (!opportunitiesToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update opportunitiesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: The test is still failing with the same line reference (19)  List<AggregateResult> result = [SELECT OpportunityId

Comment: @Merry I've updated the answer with your Netsuite trigger code as well. This update comes with no warranty. Test it thoroughly.

Comment: Unfortunately our accounting dept signed a contract with them, they have been terrible. Also unfortunate that the update of the trigger did not get the test to pass. I am going to have to put in a ticket with them to get this resolved (something I was hoping to avoid).

Comment: Mark can you look at the update I made to this. Looks like my trigger was the real culprit.